# How to get the most frequent word from a corpus?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, counter, corpus

I am working with corpuses, and want to get the most and least used word and word class from a corpus. I have the beginning of a code, but i get some errors i don't know how to deal with. I want to get the most frequent word out of the brown corpus, and then the most and least used word classes. I have this code:

```
import re
import nltk
import string
from collections import Counter
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from nltk.corpus import brown

brown = nltk.corpus.brown
stoplist = stopwords.words('english')

from collections import defaultdict

def toptenwords(brown):
    words = brown.words()
    no_capitals = ([word.lower() for word in words])
    filtered = [word for word in no_capitals if word not in stoplist]
    translate_table = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)
    no_punct = [s.translate(translate_table) for s in filtered]
    wordcounter = defaultdict(int)
    for word in no_punct:
        if word in wordcounter:
            wordcounter[word] += 1
        else:
            wordcounter[word] = 1
    sorting = [(k, wordcounter[k])for k in sorted(wordcounter, key = wordcounter.get, reverse = True)]
    return sorting

print(toptenwords(brown))

words_2 = [word[0] for word in brown.tagged_words(categories="news")]
# the most frequent words
print Counter(words_2).most_common(10)

words_2 = [word[1] for word in brown.tagged_words(categories="news")]
# the most frequent word class
print Counter(words_2).most_common(10)


# Keeps words and pos into a dictionary
# where the key is a word and
# the value is a counter of POS and counts
word_tags = defaultdict(Counter)
for word, pos in brown.tagged_words():
word_tags[word][pos] +=1

# To access the POS counter.
print 'Red', word_tags['Red']
print 'Marlowe', word_tags['Marlowe']
print

# Greatest number of distinct tag.
word_with_most_distinct_pos = sorted(word_tags, key=lambda x: len(word_tags[x]), reverse=True)[0]

print word_with_most_distinct_pos
print word_tags[word_with_most_distinct_pos]
print len(word_tags[word_with_most_distinct_pos])

# which word has the greatest number of distinct tags
word_tags_2 = nltk.defaultdict(lambda: set())
for word, token in tagged_words:
    word_tags[word].add(token)
    ambig_words = sorted([(k, len(v)) for (k, v) in word_tags.items()]),
    key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:50]
  print [(word, numtoks, word_tags[word]) for (word, numtoks) in ambig_words]
```

When i run the code above, I get the errors below:

```
File "Oblig2a.py", line 64
    key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:50]
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

From this code i would like to get:

1. Most frequent word
2. Most frequent word class
3. Least frequent word class
4. How many words with more than one word class
5. Which word has the most tags, and how many distinct tags are there
6. The last thing i need help with is to write a function to a specific  word and write how many times it appears with each of the tags. I am trying to do that above, but i cant get it to work...

It is number 3, 4, 5 and 6 i need help with...
Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: Look at the stack trace. The offending line is apparently `stoplist = stopwords.words(brown)`. This method expects file ids, but not a sequence of tagged words (which is what you assigned to the variable `brown`).

Comment: How do i change it?

Comment: You should provide the name of the language to the function, e.g. `stoplist = stopwords.words('english')`

Comment: Now it runs fine, but i am unsure how to print what i want from the output... I have tried multiple places and methods, but i don't get anything printed...

Comment: Vebjørn, have a look at the line where you define `no_capitals`, and think about what it does, and how this could affect your goal of *counting* words.

Comment: Doesn't that mean to make capital words to noncapitals words?

Comment: That's not the only thing it does, you also call `set()` on the result.

Comment: "In python, set() is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements."  I see... So i can just remove the set function, and then i can count correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems with the code:

1. The error what interpreter is telling you - you should provide name of the language to stopwords function: `stoplist = stopwords.words('english')`
2. Use `defaultdict` dictionary `get` method to properly sort the dict: 
   `[(k, wordcounter[k])for k in sorted(wordcounter, key = wordcounter.get, reverse = True)]`
3. Use translate table on Unicode data, see [string.translate() with unicode data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692199/string-translate-with-unicode-data-in-python)
4. Brown tagged words are tuples in format `(word, part-of-speech)`

Complete code:

```
import re
import nltk
import string
from collections import Counter
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

brown = nltk.corpus.brown
stoplist = stopwords.words('english')

from collections import defaultdict

def toptenwords(brown):
    words = brown.words()
    no_capitals = set([word.lower() for word in words])
    filtered = [word for word in no_capitals if word not in stoplist]
    translate_table = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)
    no_punct = [s.translate(translate_table) for s in filtered]
    wordcounter = defaultdict(int)
    for word in no_punct:
        if word in wordcounter:
            wordcounter[word] += 1
        else:
            wordcounter[word] = 1
    sorting = [(k, wordcounter[k])for k in sorted(wordcounter, key = wordcounter.get, reverse = True)]
    return sorting


print(toptenwords(brown))

words_2 = [word[0] for word in brown.tagged_words(categories="news")]
# the most frequent words
print Counter(words_2).most_common(10)

words_2 = [word[1] for word in brown.tagged_words(categories="news")]
# the most frequent word class
print Counter(words_2).most_common(10)
```

Comment: Thank you! But how do i get the least used words and word classes from this code?

Comment: Check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743035/python-3-1-obtaining-the-least-common-element-in-array

Comment: @VebjørnBergaplass, to use the nltk you need to be able to program a little. You need to narrow down "I don't get the output I want" to a programming question.

Comment: Sorry. When i run the edited code (with print), i do not get a output. I tried to run it and put the print at the end, but got nothing...