# Second smallest element in a list

Tags: python, list

I have to find the names of student(s) with second smallest grade. My code is working fine some test cases but this one in particular is troubling me:

> 4 
>   Rachel
>   -50
>   Mawer
>   -50
>   Sheen
>   -50
>   Shaheen
>   51

Output returned is

> Mawer
>   Rachel
>   Sheen

Shaheen has the 2nd smallest grade and should be the output. I am not sure where am I going wrong. Also, I am having trouble with grades as float inputs:

> 4
>   Shadab
>   8
>   Varun
>   8.9
>   Sarvesh
>   9.5
>   Harsh
>   10

Output thrown is Sarvesh when it should be Varun.

```
import heapq
# range(int(input())):
n = int(input())
builtlist = []
temp= []
names = []
for i in range(0, n):
name = input()
score = float(input())
builtlist.append([name, score])

temp = sorted(builtlist, key = lambda x: x[1])
#minvalue = min(temp, key= lambda x: x[1])

for j in range(len(temp)):
secondsmall = heapq.nsmallest(2, temp)[-1]
if (temp[j][1]==secondsmall[1]):
    names.append(temp[j][0])
list = sorted(names)
print(*list, sep = "\n")
```

I guess there's some trouble with heapq.nsmallest method I have used but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: That's because your code isn't indented

Comment: Also, a somewhat philosophical question; what is the second smallest when there are many with the same (lowest) score? You seem to consider the scores, rather than the people. That is fine, but it is worth to think about.

Comment: @e4c5 It's working fine with other inputs. These two are causing trouble. Indentation issue as in where?

Comment: as in your code or as in the code you posted in your question

Comment: @JohanL In that case, since there are multiple people with the same scores, names of all those people are getting appended in the names list. Then, I would be getting the output with all those names sorted alphabetically. That's one of the requirements of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going wrong here `temp = sorted(builtlist, key = lambda x: x[1])`
, `heapq.nsmallest(2,temp)` returns the n smallest elements in the temp, in your case it will be `[50,50,50,51]` so it'll return `[50, 50]`
use `temp = list(set(temp))` then your code will work.

you can use this code to get the same answer, in case you don't want to use heapq.

```
# range(int(input())):
n = int(input())
builtlist = []
temp= []
names = []
for i in range(0, n):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    builtlist.append([name, score])

temp = list(set([x[1] for x in builtlist]))
secondsmall = sorted(temp)[1]

for j in range(len(builtlist)):
    if (builtlist[j][1]==secondsmall):
        names.append(builtlist[j][0])
list_print = sorted(names)
print(*list_print, sep = "\n")
```

Comment: Hey thanks it looks fine but is throwing the error at secondsmall = sorted(list(set([x[1] for x in builtlist])))[1] as "list object is not callable"

Comment: I edited my answer. Actually that should work, I don't know why you got error. >>> a = [('asdas', 20), ('asdasd', 40), ('fsdgfds',20), ('dsada', 50)]
>>> sorted(list(set([x[1] for x in a])))[1]
40

Comment: >>> a = [('asdas', 20), ('asdasd', 40), ('fsdgfds',20), ('dsada', 50)] >>> sorted(list(set([x[1] for x in a])))[1] >>>40

Comment: temp = list(set([x[1] for x in builtlist])) That's very strange. On this line here, it keeps throwing the error that list object is not callable. I thought list being a built in variable might have gotten overshadowed by the list variable declared at the end but something else is the reason I guess.

Comment: yeah that might be the case here. before running a program python creates a `__dict__` which has all the variable and methods. Please avoid using the  keywords as a variable name. Edited my code. I just added my part and used rest from your code, sorry for that.

Comment: Issue sorted. Turns out the list built-in got overshadowed with list = sorted(names). I renamed it, deleted the builtin and then re-invoked it. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of things going on here.

First off, stackoverflow does not exist to debug your code and this is a misuse of the website. Please in the future do not do this, and be aware of the

```
code tags.
```

Second, heapq.nsmallest() will return the number requested of smallest elements. If two elements are the least and share a value then they both will be returned. Therefore the code is operating as intended.

I would look into python dictionaries, and hashsets for this problem. There exists a more elegant solution.

Comment: Didn't intend to misue anything as such plus my bad. I am a newbie here and still getting a hang of how everything on here works out.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't need to use `heapq`:

```
def second_smallest(builtlist):
    # sort on key.
    temp = sorted(builtlist, key = lambda x: x[1])
    second_smallest_group = []
    current_val = 0
    # iterate list comparing i with i + 1
    for i in range(len(temp) - 1):
        current_val = temp[i][1]
        # if in set of first smallest ignore.
        if current_val == temp[i+1][1] and len(second_smallest_group) == 0:
            continue
        # if in second set of smallest add.
        elif current_val == temp[i+1][1] and len(second_smallest_group) > 0: 
            second_smallest_group.append(temp[i+1][0])
        # if changing between sets add first member.
        elif len(second_smallest_group) == 0:
            second_smallest_group.append(temp[i+1][0])
        # if we move to another group break.
        else:
            break
    return second_smallest_group



builtlist = [["Rachel", -50], ["Mawer", -50], ["Sheen", -50],["Shaheen",51]]

print(second_smallest(builtlist))

builtlist = [["Shadab",8], ["Varun", 8.9], ["Sarvesh", 9.5], ["Harsh",10]]

print(second_smallest(builtlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

A more common counterpart to `heapq` in Python is a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
import collections as ct

def second_smallest(lst):
    """Return the second smallest entry."""
    c = ct.Counter()
    for name, score in lst:
        c.update({name:score})
    return c.most_common()[-2]
```

Application:

```
builtlist = [["Rachel", -50], ["Mawer", -50], ["Sheen", -50],["Shaheen", 51]]
second_smallest(builtlist)
# ('Sheen', -50)

builtlist = [["Shadab", 8], ["Varun", 8.9], ["Sarvesh", 9.5], ["Harsh", 10]]
second_smallest(builtlist)
# ('Varun', 8.9)
```

[Here are ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743035/python-3-1-obtaining-the-least-common-element-in-array) to get the least common (or smallest) value using the `Counter.most_common()` method.