# less common words in a python list

Tags: python, list, counter

I have done the counter of most common words to keep only the 128 most common words in my list in order:

```
words = my_list
mcommon_words = [word for word, word_count in Counter(words).most_common(128)]
my_list = [x for x in my_list if x in mcommon_words]
my_list = OrderedDict.fromkeys(my_list)
my_list = list(my_list.keys())
```

But now I want to count the 128 less common words in the same way. A faster solution would help me a lot too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtaining the least common element in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743035/obtaining-the-least-common-element-in-array)

Answer (score 2):

`most_common` returns the words and their counts as a list of tuples. Furthermore, [if no argument is given, it returns all the words](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common).

The fact that the method returns a list means that you can use slicing to get the first and last `n` elements.

Demo:

```
l = list("asadfabsdfasodfjoasdffsafdsa")
sorted_items = [w for w, _ in Counter(l).most_common()]

print(sorted_items[:2])  ## Print top 2 items
print(sorted_items[-2:]) ## Print last 2 items
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try the following:

```
from collections import Counter

def common_words(words, number_of_words, reverse=False):
    counter = Counter(words)
    return sorted(counter, key = counter.get, reverse=reverse)[:number_of_words]
```

Here we make sure that the Counter dictionary is sorted by its value. After the sort, we return the least most words. Here is a test example:

```
words = []
for i,num in enumerate('one two three four five six seven eight nine ten'.split()):
    words.extend([num]*(i+1))

print(common_words(words,5))
```

This example got the 5 least common words from your list of words.

Results:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

We can also get the most common words:

```
print(common_words(words,5, reverse=True))
```

Results:

```
['ten', 'nine', 'eight', 'seven', 'six']
```