# Is there any method to find the lowest occurence of an character in a string as like most_common used for maximum occurence?

Tags: python-3.x

string='hhelloo'

output must be 'e' because it is least occurred character in string.

```
lst=[1,1,2,3,4,5,5]
moc=min([(lst.count(chr),chr) for chr in (lst)])
print(moc)
```

Comment: And what if there are multiple such characters with the least occurrence?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the last element from `Counter.most_common()`

```py
from collections import Counter

print(Counter('hhelloo').most_common()[-1][0])
```

This wouldn't be very efficient however. For a more efficient method, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4743286/5946921

It implements a `least_common` function in a similar way to how `Counter.most_common` is implemented