# Find the most frequent number in a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the following NumPy array:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,2,2,1])
```

How can I find the most frequent number in this array?

Comment: For Python lists see [Find the most common element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1518522/7851470) and [Find the item with maximum occurrences in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6987285/7851470).

Answer (score 250, accepted):

If your list contains all non-negative ints, you should take a look at numpy.bincounts:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html

and then probably use np.argmax:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,2,2,1])
counts = np.bincount(a)
print(np.argmax(counts))
```

For a more complicated list (that perhaps contains negative numbers or non-integer values), you can use [`np.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) in a similar way. Alternatively, if you just want to work in python without using numpy, `collections.Counter` is a good way of handling this sort of data.

```
from collections import Counter
a = [1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,2,2,1]
b = Counter(a)
print(b.most_common(1))
```

Comment: To those of us visiting after 2016:

I dislike this answer, as bincount(arr) returns an array as large as the largest element in arr, so a small array with a large range would create an excessively large array. Apoengtus's answer below is much better, although I don't think numpy.unique() existed in 2011, when this answer was created.

Comment: @Nikolai yeah but chaining is both less readable and less debuggable than having an intermediate `counts` variable, as @JoshAdel wrote

Comment: **Python 3**: `Counter(array).most_common(1)[0][0]`

Comment: @Wehrdo There is a trade-off. `bincount` consumes more memory but is much faster. When the range is increased, `bincount` takes more space but finishes in nearly the same amount time, whereas `unique` needs much more time but takes the same amount of space.

Comment: np.bincount assumes all elements to be > 0, so this won't work if there are negative elements in the array

Comment: Choose the best tool for the job. `bincount` is not universally applicable, but it is really good when the values are positive integers with a small max bound, such as in the case of counting votes.

Answer (score 139):

You may use

```
values, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)

ind = np.argmax(counts)
print(values[ind])  # prints the most frequent element

ind = np.argpartition(-counts, kth=10)[:10]
print(values[ind])  # prints the 10 most frequent elements
```

If some element is as frequent as another one, this code will return only the first element.

Comment: I find this the most helpful as it is generic, short and allows pulling elements from values or counts by some derived index.

Comment: If we have multiple most frequent values, `values[counts.argmax()]` will return the first value. To get all of them, we can use `values[counts == counts.max()]`.

Answer (score 54):

If you're willing to use [SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html):

```
>>> from scipy.stats import mode
>>> mode([1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,2,2,1])
(array([ 1.]), array([ 6.]))
>>> most_frequent = mode([1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,2,2,1])[0][0]
>>> most_frequent
1.0
```

Answer (score 36):

## Performances (using iPython) for some solutions found here:

```
>>> # small array
>>> a = [12,3,65,33,12,3,123,888000]
>>> 
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter(a).most_common()[0][0]
3
>>> %timeit collections.Counter(a).most_common()[0][0]
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.3 µs per loop
>>> 
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.bincount(a).argmax()
3
>>> %timeit numpy.bincount(a).argmax()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.84 ms per loop
>>> 
>>> import scipy.stats
>>> scipy.stats.mode(a)[0][0]
3.0
>>> %timeit scipy.stats.mode(a)[0][0]
10000 loops, best of 3: 172 µs per loop
>>> 
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> def jjc(l):
...     d = defaultdict(int)
...     for i in a:
...         d[i] += 1
...     return sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0]
... 
>>> jjc(a)[0]
3
>>> %timeit jjc(a)[0]
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.58 µs per loop
>>> 
>>> max(map(lambda val: (a.count(val), val), set(a)))[1]
12
>>> %timeit max(map(lambda val: (a.count(val), val), set(a)))[1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.11 µs per loop
>>>
```

Best is 'max' with 'set' **for small arrays** like the problem.

According to @David Sanders, if you increase the array size to something like 100,000 elements, the "max w/set" algorithm ends up **being the worst by far** whereas the "numpy bincount" method is the best.

Comment: @IuliusCurt in order to point the best approach we need to test it against multiple cases: small arrays, large arrays, random arrays, real world arrays (like [timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) does for sorting), ... But I agree with you

Comment: Using only a small array, as in your approach, isn't going to distinguish very well between the different algorithms.

Comment: If you increase the test list size to 100000 (`a = (np.random.rand(100000) * 1000).round().astype('int'); a_list = list(a)`), your "max w/set" algorithm ends up being the worst by far whereas the "numpy bincount" method is the best.  I conducted this test using `a_list` for native python code and `a` for numpy code to avoid marshalling costs screwing up the results.

Answer (score 9):

Starting in `Python 3.4`, the standard library includes the [`statistics.mode`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/statistics.html?highlight=mode#statistics.mode) function to return the single most common data point.

```
from statistics import mode

mode([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1])
# 1
```

If there are multiple modes with the same frequency, `statistics.mode` returns the first one encountered.

---

Starting in `Python 3.8`, the [`statistics.multimode`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/statistics.html?highlight=mode#statistics.multimode) function returns a list of the most frequently occurring values in the order they were first encountered:

```
from statistics import multimode

multimode([1, 2, 3, 1, 2])
# [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 5):

Also if you want to get most frequent value(positive or negative) without loading any modules you can use the following code:

```
lVals = [1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,2,2,1]
print max(map(lambda val: (lVals.count(val), val), set(lVals)))
```

Comment: This is from a while ago, but for posterity: this is equivalent to the easier-to-read `max(set(lVals), key=lVals.count)`, which does an O(n) count for each unique element of `lVals` for approximately O(n^2) (assuming O(n) unique elements). Using `collections.Counter(lVals).most_common(1)[0][0]` from the standard library, as [suggested by JoshAdel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6252400/344821), is only O(n).

Answer (score 4):

While most of the answers above are useful, in case you:
1) need it to support non-positive-integer values (e.g. floats or negative integers ;-)), and
2) aren't on Python 2.7 (which collections.Counter requires), and
3) prefer not to add the dependency of scipy (or even numpy) to your code, then a purely python 2.6 solution that is O(nlogn) (i.e., efficient) is just this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,2,2,1]

d = defaultdict(int)
for i in a:
  d[i] += 1
most_frequent = sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3 the following should work:

```
max(set(a), key=lambda x: a.count(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the solution by JoshAdel.

But there is just one catch.

The `np.bincount()` solution only works on numbers.

If you have strings, `collections.Counter` solution will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general solution that may be applied along an axis, regardless of values, using purely numpy.  I've also found that this is much faster than scipy.stats.mode if there are a lot of unique values.

```
import numpy

def mode(ndarray, axis=0):
    # Check inputs
    ndarray = numpy.asarray(ndarray)
    ndim = ndarray.ndim
    if ndarray.size == 1:
        return (ndarray[0], 1)
    elif ndarray.size == 0:
        raise Exception('Cannot compute mode on empty array')
    try:
        axis = range(ndarray.ndim)[axis]
    except:
        raise Exception('Axis "{}" incompatible with the {}-dimension array'.format(axis, ndim))

    # If array is 1-D and numpy version is > 1.9 numpy.unique will suffice
    if all([ndim == 1,
            int(numpy.__version__.split('.')[0]) >= 1,
            int(numpy.__version__.split('.')[1]) >= 9]):
        modals, counts = numpy.unique(ndarray, return_counts=True)
        index = numpy.argmax(counts)
        return modals[index], counts[index]

    # Sort array
    sort = numpy.sort(ndarray, axis=axis)
    # Create array to transpose along the axis and get padding shape
    transpose = numpy.roll(numpy.arange(ndim)[::-1], axis)
    shape = list(sort.shape)
    shape[axis] = 1
    # Create a boolean array along strides of unique values
    strides = numpy.concatenate([numpy.zeros(shape=shape, dtype='bool'),
                                 numpy.diff(sort, axis=axis) == 0,
                                 numpy.zeros(shape=shape, dtype='bool')],
                                axis=axis).transpose(transpose).ravel()
    # Count the stride lengths
    counts = numpy.cumsum(strides)
    counts[~strides] = numpy.concatenate([[0], numpy.diff(counts[~strides])])
    counts[strides] = 0
    # Get shape of padded counts and slice to return to the original shape
    shape = numpy.array(sort.shape)
    shape[axis] += 1
    shape = shape[transpose]
    slices = [slice(None)] * ndim
    slices[axis] = slice(1, None)
    # Reshape and compute final counts
    counts = counts.reshape(shape).transpose(transpose)[slices] + 1

    # Find maximum counts and return modals/counts
    slices = [slice(None, i) for i in sort.shape]
    del slices[axis]
    index = numpy.ogrid[slices]
    index.insert(axis, numpy.argmax(counts, axis=axis))
    return sort[index], counts[index]
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28736715/5775959), applied to finding the mode of the data where you may need the index of the actual array to see how far away the value is from the center of the distribution.

```
(_, idx, counts) = np.unique(a, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
index = idx[np.argmax(counts)]
mode = a[index]
```

Remember to discard the mode when len(np.argmax(counts)) > 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach:

```
x = np.array([[2, 5, 5, 2], [2, 7, 8, 5], [2, 5, 7, 9]])
u, c = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
print(u[c == np.amax(c)])
```

This will give the answer: `array([2, 5])`

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.bincount` and the `np.argmax` method can get the most common value in a numpy array. If your array is an image array, use the `np.ravel` or `np.flatten()` methods to convert a ndarray to a 1-dimensional array.

Answer (score -1):

I'm recently doing a project and using collections.Counter.(Which tortured me).

The Counter in collections have a very very bad performance in my opinion. It's just a class wrapping dict().

What's worse,  If you use cProfile to profile its method, you should see a lot of '__missing__' and '__instancecheck__' stuff wasting the whole time.

Be careful using its most_common(), because everytime it would invoke a sort which makes it extremely slow. and if you use most_common(x), it will invoke a heap sort, which is also slow.

Btw, numpy's bincount also have a problem: if you use np.bincount([1,2,4000000]), you will get an array with 4000000 elements.

Comment: A dict is the most finely-tuned data structure in Python and is ideal for counting arbitrary objects.   In contrast, binning only works on numerical values and doesn't let you prevent aliasing between closely spaced discrete values.    In the case of Counter, the \_\_missing\_\_ method is only called when an element is first seen; otherwise, its presence is cost-free.   Note, the *most_common()* method is blazingly fast in most cases because the heap is very small compared to the total dataset.  In most cases, the *most_common()* method makes only slightly more comparisons than *min()*.