# How to optimize python loop for 100000 iterations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I'm new to python and I'm trying to write a function whose description is as follows:
I have a list of integers. From this list I have to find the item with max frequency and print that.
This seems pretty straight forward unless I have a limitation that the function must complete the **execution within 10 sec and should consume memory < 512 MB**. For shorter list length my function works fine but for a list of length 100000 it tanks. I'm not able to optimize the code.
I have 2 implementations for the same:

Implementation #1

```
def returnMaxFrequency(ar):
    freqList = []
    for val in ar:
        freq = ar.count(val)
        freqList.append(freq)
    return(max(freqList))
```

Implementation #2

```
def returnMaxFrequency(ar):   
    freqDict = {x:ar.count(x) for x in ar}   
    maxFreq = max(freqDict.values())
    return maxFreq
```

Eg

```
if ar = [3 2 1 3]
o/p: 2
```

Using NumPy is not an option here. (Can't use external package)

Comment: Take a look at `numba`.

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami it is mentioned that external package can't be used

Comment: Can you use an inbuilt module?

Comment: In what ways don't the answers provided here not solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1518522/1025391 (this especially: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20872750/1025391)

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami, yes inbuilt modules can be used

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python- find the item with maximum occurrences in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987285/python-find-the-item-with-maximum-occurrences-in-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your implementations are basically the same, the second one only uses a list comprehension instead of the for loop. Both algorithms are in `O(n^2)` because `count` is in `O(n)` and you are calling it `n` times (once for each value).

If you want to optimize, reduce the complexity (to `O(n)`):

```
def returnMaxFrequency(ar):   
    freqDict = {x:0 for x in ar}
    for val in ar:
        freqDict[val] = freqDict[val] + 1
    maxFreq = max(freqDict.values())
    return maxFreq
```

Comment: You can skip the dict initialization by using `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: defaultdict is not required to skip dictionary initialization. `dict.get(key,[default=0])` will do

Answer (score 4):

Easiest (and reasonably fast) is likely the built-in `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
winner = Counter(ar).most_common(1)[0]
```

An even faster method (and using no extra memory, but destroying the original array) is given in [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-repeating-number-in-ok-time/), replicated here:

```
# Python program to find the maximum repeating number 

# Returns maximum repeating element in arr[0..n-1]. 
# The array elements are in range from 0 to k-1 
def maxRepeating(arr, n,  k): 

    # Iterate though input array, for every element 
    # arr[i], increment arr[arr[i]%k] by k 
    for i in range(0,  n): 
        arr[arr[i]%k] += k 

    # Find index of the maximum repeating element 
    max = arr[0] 
    result = 0
    for i in range(1, n): 

        if arr[i] > max: 
            max = arr[i] 
            result = i 

    # Uncomment this code to get the original array back 
    #for i in range(0, n): 
    #    arr[i] = arr[i]%k 

    # Return index of the maximum element 
    return result
```

(Parts of this code could be replaced by more performant alternates, in particular using the `max` function instead of the second loop.)

Comment: He wrote he can't even use `numpy` as he "Can't use external package"

Comment: @Aryerez: `collections` is not an external package.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps!

We are using Python's High-Performance container datatypes(`Counter`)

```
from collections import Counter

def returnMaxFrequency(ar):
    return max(Counter(t).values())
```

`Counter` does a frequency mapping of your number and created a `dict`, once `dict` is created you are using a `max` to get max-freq of the list.

Using Dict is an efficient way of generating a frequency count, unless your are going for distributed compute solutions

Note: `collections` is a python in-built package i.e. comes with setup. Not an external library.

Comment: He wrote he can't even use `numpy` as he "Can't use external package"

Comment: @Aryerez - It's in-built package. Here is a link for your reference - https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Comment: Regarding "High-Performance container datatypes": `Counter` is implemented in Python, and is no more performant than the `dict` solution, just more readable and succint. It is way faster than any solution involving `count`, though.

Comment: @Amadan - thanks! can you prove if `dict` has faster performance than `Counter`?

Comment: `Counter` uses `dict` ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L472)). Thus, a solution using `Counter` is doing almost the same thing as the solution using `dict`, just in one case it's you who needs to write the counting code, and in the other it's the Python developers who've already done it for you. (`Counter` would be a little bit slower because it does a bit more checking of parameter correctness and types which a custom `dict` solution would not be doing.)

Comment: @Amadan I just reran the timings given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6988979/1025391) and it seems `Counter` is actually faster than solutions based on `dict` and `defaultdict` for recent Python versions (tested this with v3.6.7).

Comment: For reference: [tio](https://tio.run/##rZLBcsIgEIbveQomJ6g0k9hEZzqTU6@@gXUyEdEyBkiBdJqnTxfQaquHHhq48P@7y8dm@9G9afX0aF3Ljh23dpqE7LVxyI422RstEdNdx5kTWll08l70oBw3FO34vh06txPMxWABstO6@w49GD302zG6uuemddqcTYiWB@4gJ/pOSC7c2Y2nJFmhGq0LOqdlRSvYtLxaVVktKOwFXdLFcvNQ5HmeJMCFZPvZaMYGY7hi3DYFtvy9XpHnBMGXeuaA6yFsGkQGN3kdk3Dce1JwkVAIcmNiiFt7eQPRLAN@7E8U5QTNUBGCDHeDUR4BsyxcgAlFRz7WlyfjgpD7pPNfpJcm3wW@2Fgo90f0Wf0vqOVPVBYHI72ufBoWvCKZ1NY1TEupFZRc55sk@eDGhtGCf3xTnN625lYqoEpv4OUYRjY71aMofVUpQPtGeM034nxXhI05XsuaZqdZ09AQ4Z8fRy@YFKlBbrmp53lOyDR9AQ)

Comment: @moooeeeep: My bad — I just saw a C helper function that Python loads "if available" (`_collections._count_elements`). Without it, it does the same as I said before, but with it, it is indeed faster. This is the only sped-up part, so my eyes just skipped over it.

Comment: @moooeeeep, Amadan - Thanks to you. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

Returns most frequently occurring value in `list`

```
max(set(ar), key=ar.count)
```

Comment: It needs to be added that this has horrible algorithmic complexity.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?:

```
max(ar.count(i) for i in ar)
```

Or this?:

```
max(map(ar.count,ar))
```

Comment: Solutions iterating the input list more than once are inferior.

Answer (score 0):

The second implement is nice, but inside the dict-comprehension change `ar` to `set(ar)`, and it will check every item only once:

```
def returnMaxFrequency(ar):   
    freqDict = {x:ar.count(x) for x in set(ar)}   
    maxFreq = max(freqDict.values())
    return maxFreq
```