# How to find the probability of a number being most repeated in a list in python?

Tags: python

I am being asked to output the probability of a number most repeated for every dice until dice N rolled P times. 
The code I have now is:

```
import random
N = int(input("Insert Number: "))
P = int(input("Insert Number again: "))
for x in range (1,N+1):
    print("Dice",x)
    n = random.sample(range(1,6), P)
    print(n)
```

Can someone help me move on to the step to calculate the possibility of the most repeated number for each dice?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987285/python-find-the-item-with-maximum-occurrences-in-a-list This might help

Comment: I don't really get it. Aren't the probabilities all the same?

Comment: Nah if you roll N dice say N is 2, 7 is the most common sum of the values on the two dice.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a python question per se as much as a probability question. That notwithstanding, there are basically two methods that readily come to mind.

1. **Exact Solution** - You can enumerate all of the possible sums combinations of dice for N dice, then find every possible permutation of these sum combinations, and then perform a simple check to determine which of the permutations satisfy the condition that the designated value is the most common sum of dice.
2. **Monte Carlo Simulations** - You can  simulate the rolling of N dice, P times, and record the most commonly rolled sum. Repeat this a sufficiently large number of times and then use the result to estimate the probability.