# how do you convert a for loop output into a list?

Tags: python, list

I've been through some answers to similar questions on stackoverflow, whereas I appears to be facing a quite delicate situation wherein some of them won't work. below is my code:

```py
import random
from datetime import datetime
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
def log():
    print(random.choice(array))

characters_to_remove = ".-:"
now = str(datetime.now()).replace(" ", "")
for character in characters_to_remove:
    now = now.replace(character, "")

# print(now)
time = now
time = int(time)
# print(time)

paramTime = time % 535
# print(paramTime)

# param = int(str(paramTime)[:2])
param = int(str(paramTime)[:1])
# print(param)

def repeat(times, func):
    for i in range(param): func()

print(repeat(param, log))
# print(str(repeat(param, log)).split(""))
# print('----------')
```

as you can see, the for loop is used in order to call a function (for multiple times):

```py
def repeat(param, func):
    # param stands for the number of times the function is to be called
    for i in range(param): func()
```

now I want to convert my outputs as a list and ergo be able to get the most commonly outputted value... what do I do?

Comment: You can modify your function and return the values, which you can append in a list.

Comment: You mean you want to create a list out of values that `func` returns? Or does `func` print something to standard output and you want to capture that?

Comment: @LevM. I want to create a list out of values that `func` returns. @quamrana below had a correct understanding. cheers anyway mate!

Comment: why do I have negative votes tho... I think I am losing the privilege to ask on stackoverflow 

Comment: Sorry, yes you need upvotes for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no good way to convert the output of a `print()` into values that can be collected.

You just need functions which return values and a loop which collects them:

```py
import random

array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
def choose():
    return random.choice(array)

def repeat(param, func):
    # param stands for the number of times the function is to be called
    return [func() for _ in range(param)]

# ...
# other parts elided

print(repeat(param, choose))
```

The expected output is a `list` which you can examine or manipulate further.

Also, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40785493) for a way to get the most popular value.

You can use it like this:

```py
def get_max(l):
    return max(l, key=l.count) 

print(get_max(repeat(param,log)))
```

Comment: You are so quick! I was about the post the answer but my answer is almost the same as yours!

Comment: @Sujay: He he! I expected you to be here. :-) It just goes to show that sometimes there is just one way to solve a problem.

Comment: ah I see... that's really stupid of me. I am really new to python cos I am a frontend so I asked this silly question... sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

1. return the value from `log` function
2. Use `collections.counter` to get the most common element.

```
import collections
....
def log():
    return random.choice(array)

....
def get_max(l):
    return max(collections.Counter(l))
def repeat(times, func):
    return [func() for i in range(times)]

print(get_max(repeat(param,log)))
```

Comment: well, appears to me you have yet another solution!

Comment: Ok, @Sujay. I think you've gone a bit too far. You should split your `repeat()` into two functions: 1. the `repeat()` that I have, plus 2. A new function which does the `max()` and `Counter()` thing. Then they are both reuseable.

Comment: `max(collections.Counter([1, 1, 1, 2]))` returns 2.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to generalize `log` to print to a given file, not just standard output.

```
def log(fh=sys.stdout):
    print(random.choice(array), file=fh)
```

Then you can make multiple calls that write to a single `io.StringIO` object, from which you can get a single string containing everything written to the file. Splitting that string on newlines may be sufficient.

```
my_log = io.StringIO()
repeat(param, lambda: log(my_log))
my_log.seek(0)

for x in my_log:
    print(x.strip())
```

You could also define your own file-like class that appends its arguments to a list. Something like

```
class Collector:
    def __init__(self):
         self.lines = []
    def write(self, line):
        self.lines.append(line)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.lines

my_log = Collector()
repeat(param, log(my_log))

# my_log.lines is just a list of the strings produced by each call to log
```

Comment: I actually thought about this and thought it wouldn't be the most elegant of solutions... and so I stackoverflowed it and everything. but hey, at least you prove me smart... somehow... to came to an agreement with people like you. thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change your `log` function (i.e. it belongs to a third-party library), you could change the value of `sys.stdout` using [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

```
import io
import contextlib

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(io.StringIO()) as fake_stdout:
    # ...
```

Change `# ...` with your calculation and at the end access the outputted values using `fake_stdout.getvalue()`:

```
import io
import contextlib

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(io.String()) as fake_stdout:
    import random
    
    def log():
        print(random.randint(1, 10))
        
    def repeat(param, func):
        for i in range(param): 
            func()

    repeat(10, log)

print(fake_stdout.getvalue())
```

The above outputs

```
6
9
10
10
4
9
10
8
5
3
```

To convert it to a list and manipulate it, just do

```
outputs = fake_stdout.getvalue().strip().split()
print(outputs)
# Outputs ['6', '9', '10', '10', '4', '9', '10', '8', '5', '3']

import collections
print(collections.Counter(outputs).most_common(1)[0][0])
# Outputs 10
```

Comment: Yes, and this is the answer I was hoping no one would write. You can do these things, but you have to be careful to restore `stdout` after, just as you have demonstrated.

Comment: yea I tested your code and it worked like a charm... but it seems longish and @quamrana made a fair point too. I really appreciate your work though!

Comment: @quamrana I've added a safer alternative, thanks for the hint!