# Finding most frequent number in a list, TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: list, python-3.x, collections

The following python code passes a 2D array to a `opportunity()`. In the function, each row is checked for a length greater that the predefined size. If the condition is true, the hth element is appended in a list.

Next, the array is searched for the most frequent number in it.

```
from collections import Counter
def opportunity(a,h):
   ar = []
   ar.append( [row[h] for row in a if len(row)>h] )
   b = Counter(ar)
   return b.most_common(1)

next = opportunity(take, head)
```

So, for an input like

```
1 3 3
2 4
5 2 4 6 2
4 3 6 1
3 7 2 6 1 5
```

Assume `h=3`, the output must be

```
ar = [6 1 6]
next = 6
```

But I get this error

```
File "c:\Users\mahmood\python_ws\first.py", line 43, in <module>
  next = opportunity(take, head)
File "c:\Users\mahmood\python_ws\first.py", line 12, in opportunity
  b = Counter(ar)
File "C:\Python34\Lib\collections\__init__.py", line 475, in __init__
  self.update(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\Python34\Lib\collections\__init__.py", line 562, in update
  _count_elements(self, iterable)

builtins.TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new list by using a list comprehension, so instead of appending that to ar (the cause of your problem because counter can't count lists), just do the list comprehension in Counter.

Here is how you can accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.

```
# Create a one dimensional list using a list comprehension which gets the h'th element if the length of row > h
def opportunity(a,h):
    ar = [row[h] for row in a if len(row)>h]
    return Counter(ar).most_common(1)
```

Comment: I saw an example on 1D array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252280/find-the-most-frequent-number-in-a-numpy-vector

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: By appending the list comprehension row[h] for row in a if len (row) > h to your list 'ar', you've created a two dimensional list, which won't work with Counter, because it accepts one dimensional lists or other iterable type. So your alternative is to pass the list comprehension directly to Counter, or assign it to a variable and pass that.

Comment: OK I understand. Now, what is returned is ('6',2). I tried `a = opportunity(take, head)` and then `next = int(a[0])` but it doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, most_common returns a list of pairs, where each pair contains (key, count).

Comment: By the way. Using the fashion that I used (append), the correct way to pass `ar` to Counter is `Counter(ar[0])` so the 1D list is passed correctly. However, I prefer your method

Comment: Good. I don't care for the fact that most_common returns a list even for a single most frequent item, but it is what it is.