# Ansible. Determine most popular value in array

Tags: python, ansible, cisco

```
 tasks:

   - name: Find popular vlan
     ios_command:
       provider: "{{ cli }}"
       commands:
         - show run | i switchport access vlan
     register: sh_res

   - debug: var=sh_res
```

Debug sh_res is look like this:

```
  "stdout_lines": [
            [
                "switchport access vlan 40", 
                " switchport access vlan 22", 
                " switchport access vlan 22", 
                " switchport access vlan 22", 
                " switchport access vlan 22", 
                " switchport access vlan 22", 
                " switchport access vlan 22", 
                " switchport access vlan 22", 
                " switchport access vlan 22", 
                " switchport access vlan 30", 
                " switchport access vlan 20", 
                " switchport access vlan 22", 
                " switchport access vlan 22", 
                " switchport access vlan 22", 
                " switchport access vlan 22", 
                " switchport access vlan 22", 
                " switchport access vlan 22", 
                " switchport access vlan 22", 
                " switchport access vlan 22"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to determine most popular vlan on the switch and put in into variable {{vlan}}. In this case it is 22. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should reach all of vlan:

```
stdout_lines = sh_res['stdout_lines'][0]
vlans = [line.split()[-1] for line in stdout_lines] #['40', '22', ..., '22', '22']
```

After that you just need to find most frequent item in vlans. [Check this topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252280/find-the-most-frequent-number-in-a-numpy-vector) Counter from collections can be used to find most frequent item.

```
from collections import Counter

vlanCounter = Counter(vlans)
print(vlanCounter.most_common(1)) #[('22', 16)]
print(vlanCounter.most_common(1)[0][0]) #'22'
```