# How to find the maximum occuring label(element) in a numpy array?

Tags: python

Basically I want to build a function to ACCEPT a non-empty numpy array of labels as input , RETURN the value that appears most frequently in that array. In the case of of a tie, RETURN the value in the tie that appears first in the array.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please share some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the most frequent number in a numpy vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252280/find-the-most-frequent-number-in-a-numpy-vector)

Answer (score 1):

Resuing the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28736715/4578111

```
def frequent_label(labels):
    (values,counts) = np.unique(labels,return_counts=True)
    ind=np.argmax(counts)
    return values[ind]
```

Comment: if you find this answer helpful, please mark it as accepted answer, and feel free to upvote.