# What is the alternative for numpy bincount when using negative integers?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm using `numpy.bincount` to find the most common int in an array like this:

```
labels=np.array([1,2,2,3,4])    
np.bincount(labels).argmax()
```

But bincount would only accept positive int, is there an alternative for negative integers?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible dupe of: [Find the most frequent number in a numpy vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252280/find-the-most-frequent-number-in-a-numpy-vector)

Comment: @ParitoshSingh your example is for positive int only

Comment: read further, it talks about what to do in other cases. Specifically: histogram or counters

Comment: You're right.. thanks