# Find the N most frequent numbers in a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

[The accepted answer of the most frequent occurrence is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252280/find-the-most-frequent-number-in-a-numpy-array)

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,2,2,1])
counts = np.bincount(a)
print(np.argmax(counts))
```

But I'm wondering if anybody has an elegant way of finding the top 10 most frequent, for example.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
for i in range(10):
  largest = np.argmax(counts)
  counts[largest] = 0
  print(largest)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a very nice answer in the original post that I had missed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28736715/12279207)
from [Apogentus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1796223/apogentus)

```
values, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)

ind = np.argmax(counts)
print(values[ind])  # prints the most frequent element

ind = np.argpartition(-counts, kth=10)[:10]
print(values[ind])  # prints the 10 most frequent elements
```