# Finding the mode of a list

Tags: python, mode

Given a list of items, recall that the *mode* of the list is the item that occurs most often.

I would like to know how to create a function that can find the mode of a list but that displays a message if the list does not have a mode (e.g., all the items in the list only appear once). I want to make this function without importing any functions. I'm trying to make my own function from scratch.

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain what exactly you mean by 'mode of the list'?

Comment: @Vikas: the mode is the most frequently-occurring element (if any). Some definitions extend it to take the arithmetic mean of all such elements if there are more than one.

Comment: So many wrong answers here! For e.g `assert(mode[1, 1, 1]) == None` and 
`assert(mode[1, 2, 3, 4]) == None`. For a number to be a `mode`, it must occur more number of times than at least one other number in the list, and it must _not_ be the only number in the list.

Answer (score 203):

You can use the `max` function and a key. Have a look at [python max function using 'key' and lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296755/python-max-function-using-key-and-lambda-expression).

```
max(set(lst), key=lst.count)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to OP, considering it does not require any extra imports.  Good job, David

Comment: It seems to me that this would run in `O(n**2)`. Does it?

Comment: This has quadratic runtime

Comment: Can someone explain the choice of key to me in this answer? The example keys in the link are all transformations whereas list.count should be a static numeric value right?

Comment: @BenDot list.count is a function that returns the number of times an element occurs in the list in O(n) time.

Comment: Could also just use `max(lst, key=lst.count)`. (And I'd really not call a list `list`.)

Comment: error if lst is empty, but this can be easily solved.

Comment: Can anyone explain how this works for bi-modal distributions? e.g. `a = [22, 33, 11, 22, 11]; print(max(set(a), key=a.count))` returns `11`. Will it always return the minimum mode? And if so, why?

Comment: @battey No, `max(set(a), key=a.count)` of `a = [33, 33, 22, 22, 11, 11]` returns 33, so your assumption is false..

Comment: @StefanPochmann you really want `max(set(lst), key=lst.count)`, the reason is that you only want to run list.count once for each unique element, without the `set` even though the output is correct, you end up re-running count for duplicate elements.

Comment: @khuang834. That's the least of your complexity problems

Answer (score 117):

You can use the [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) supplied in the [`collections`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) package which has a `mode`-esque function

```
from collections import Counter
data = Counter(your_list_in_here)
data.most_common()   # Returns all unique items and their counts
data.most_common(1)  # Returns the highest occurring item
```

Note: Counter is new in python 2.7 and is not available in earlier versions.

Comment: The question states that the user wants to make a function from scratch -- i.e., no imports.

Comment: Your last line returns a list containing a tuple containing a mode and its frequency. To get just a mode use `Counter(your_list_in_here).most_common(1)[0][0]`. If there is more than one mode this returns an arbitrary one.

Comment: Suppose there are `n` most common `modes`. If Counter(your_list_in_here).most_common(1)[0][0] gets you the first mode, how would you get another most common `mode` ? Just replace the last `0` with `1`? One can make a function to customize the `mode` to their liking..

Comment: if there is more than one mode, how can I return the largest of these numbers?

Comment: If you just want the highest occuring item, it should be `data.most_common(1)[0][0]`.

Comment: @AkinHwan `max(data.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))` or with `from operator import itemgetter`, you can rewrite this `max(data.items(), key=itemgetter(1,0))`

Answer (score 78):

Python 3.4 includes the method [`statistics.mode`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html#statistics.mode), so it is straightforward:

```
>>> from statistics import mode
>>> mode([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4])
 3
```

You can have any type of elements in the list, not just numeric:

```
>>> mode(["red", "blue", "blue", "red", "green", "red", "red"])
 'red'
```

Comment: Throws error on using mode([1, 1,1,1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]) where 1 and 3 repeat equal number of time. Ideally, should return smallest of the number which largest but equal number of times.
StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 2 equally common values

Comment: Haven't used this 3.4 statistics package, but scipy.stats.mode will return the smallest, in this case 1. I would, however, prefer the throw of the error in certain cases...

Comment: @aman_novice, the issue was solved in Python 3.8.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mode

Comment: python 3.8 also added [`multimode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.multimode), which returns multiple modes when there is more than one.

Answer (score 34):

Taking a leaf from some statistics software, namely [SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) and [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/mode.html), these just return the smallest most common value, so if two values occur equally often, the smallest of these are returned. Hopefully an example will help:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import mode

>>> mode([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
(array([ 1.]), array([ 1.]))

>>> mode([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5])
(array([ 2.]), array([ 2.]))

>>> mode([1, 2, 2, -3, -3, 4, 5])
(array([-3.]), array([ 2.]))
```

Is there any reason why you can 't follow this convention?

Comment: Why only the smallest mode is returned when there are multiple?

Comment: @zyxue simple statistical convention

Comment: @chrisfs and to make it return the largest mode if there are multiple?

Answer (score 31):

There are many simple ways to find the mode of a list in Python such as:

```
import statistics
statistics.mode([1,2,3,3])
>>> 3
```

Or, you could find the max by its count

```
max(array, key = array.count)
```

The problem with those two methods are that they don't work with multiple modes. The first returns an error, while the second returns the first mode.

In order to find the modes of a set, you could use this function:

```
def mode(array):
    most = max(list(map(array.count, array)))
    return list(set(filter(lambda x: array.count(x) == most, array)))
```

Comment: Using the mode, gives error when there are two elements occur same amount of time.

Comment: Sorry, saw this comment really late. Statistics.mode(array) would return an error with multiple modes, but none of the other methods do.

Comment: (1) It is described as a data points with the highest frequency
(2) There can be multiple modes in a dataset
(3) In case continuous values, it might not be a possible to find the mode  (since all the values will be unique)
(4) It can be used over non-numeric data as well

Answer (score 7):

Extending the Community answer that will not work when the list is empty, here is working code for mode:

```
def mode(arr):
        if arr==[]:
            return None
        else:
            return max(set(arr), key=arr.count)
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you are interested in either the smallest, largest or all modes:

```
def get_small_mode(numbers, out_mode):
    counts = {k:numbers.count(k) for k in set(numbers)}
    modes = sorted(dict(filter(lambda x: x[1] == max(counts.values()), counts.items())).keys())
    if out_mode=='smallest':
        return modes[0]
    elif out_mode=='largest':
        return modes[-1]
    else:
        return modes
```

Answer (score 3):

A little longer, but can have multiple modes and can get string with most counts or mix of datatypes.

```
def getmode(inplist):
    '''with list of items as input, returns mode
    '''
    dictofcounts = {}
    listofcounts = []
    for i in inplist:
        countofi = inplist.count(i) # count items for each item in list
        listofcounts.append(countofi) # add counts to list
        dictofcounts[i]=countofi # add counts and item in dict to get later
    maxcount = max(listofcounts) # get max count of items
    if maxcount ==1:
        print "There is no mode for this dataset, values occur only once"
    else:
        modelist = [] # if more than one mode, add to list to print out
        for key, item in dictofcounts.iteritems():
            if item ==maxcount: # get item from original list with most counts
                modelist.append(str(key))
        print "The mode(s) are:",' and '.join(modelist)
        return modelist
```

Answer (score 3):

Mode of a data set is/are the member(s) that occur(s) most frequently in the set. If there are two members that appear most often with same number of times, then the data has two modes. This is called bimodal.

If there are more than 2 modes, then the data would be called multimodal. If all the members in the data set appear the same number of times, then the data set has no mode at all.

Following function modes() can work to find mode(s) in a given list of data:

```
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd

def modes(arr):
    df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['Values'])
    dat = pd.crosstab(df['Values'], columns=['Freq'])
    if len(np.unique((dat['Freq']))) > 1:
        mode = list(dat.index[np.array(dat['Freq'] == max(dat['Freq']))])
        return mode
    else:
        print("There is NO mode in the data set")
```

Output:

```
# For a list of numbers in x as
In [1]: x = [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 12, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 6, 12, 3, 7, 8, 9, 7, 12, 10, 10, 11, 12, 2]
In [2]: modes(x)
Out[2]: [2, 3, 12]
# For a list of repeated numbers in y as
In [3]: y = [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 10, 10]
In [4]: modes(y)
Out[4]: There is NO mode in the data set
# For a list of strings/characters in z as
In [5]: z = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'g', 'c', 'g', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a']
In [6]: modes(z)
Out[6]: ['a', 'g']
```

If we do not want to import `numpy` or `pandas` to call any function from these packages, then to get this same output, `modes()` function can be written as:

```
def modes(arr):
    cnt = []
    for i in arr:
        cnt.append(arr.count(i))
    uniq_cnt = []
    for i in cnt:
        if i not in uniq_cnt:
            uniq_cnt.append(i)
    if len(uniq_cnt) > 1:
        m = []
        for i in list(range(len(cnt))):
            if cnt[i] == max(uniq_cnt):
                m.append(arr[i])
        mode = []
        for i in m:
            if i not in mode:
                mode.append(i)
        return mode
    else:
        print("There is NO mode in the data set")
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote up this handy function to find the mode.

```
def mode(nums):
    corresponding={}
    occurances=[]
    for i in nums:
            count = nums.count(i)
            corresponding.update({i:count})

    for i in corresponding:
            freq=corresponding[i]
            occurances.append(freq)

    maxFreq=max(occurances)

    keys=corresponding.keys()
    values=corresponding.values()

    index_v = values.index(maxFreq)
    global mode
    mode = keys[index_v]
    return mode
```

Comment: This method will fail if 2 items have same no. of occurences.

Answer (score 2):

Short, but somehow ugly:

```
def mode(arr) :
    m = max([arr.count(a) for a in arr])
    return [x for x in arr if arr.count(x) == m][0] if m>1 else None
```

Using a dictionary, slightly less ugly:

```
def mode(arr) :
    f = {}
    for a in arr : f[a] = f.get(a,0)+1
    m = max(f.values())
    t = [(x,f[x]) for x in f if f[x]==m]
    return m > 1 t[0][0] else None
```

Answer (score 2):

This function returns the mode or modes of a function no matter how many, as well as the frequency of the mode or modes in the dataset. If there is no mode (ie. all items occur only once), the function returns an error string. This is similar to A_nagpal's function above but is, in my humble opinion, more complete, and I think it's easier to understand for any Python novices (such as yours truly) reading this question to understand.

```
 def l_mode(list_in):
    count_dict = {}
    for e in (list_in):   
        count = list_in.count(e)
        if e not in count_dict.keys():
            count_dict[e] = count
    max_count = 0 
    for key in count_dict: 
        if count_dict[key] >= max_count:
            max_count = count_dict[key]
    corr_keys = [] 
    for corr_key, count_value in count_dict.items():
        if count_dict[corr_key] == max_count:
            corr_keys.append(corr_key)
    if max_count == 1 and len(count_dict) != 1: 
        return 'There is no mode for this data set. All values occur only once.'
    else: 
        corr_keys = sorted(corr_keys)
        return corr_keys, max_count
```

Comment: I say this only because you said "the function returns an error string." The line that reads `return 'There is no mode for this data set. All values occur only once.'` can be turned into an error message with `traceback` as `if condition: *next line with indent* raise ValueError('There is no mode for this data set. All values occur only once.') [Here is a list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) of different types of errors you can raise.

Answer (score 2):

For a number to be a `mode`, it must occur more number of times than *at least one other number* in the list, and it must *not* be the only number in the list. So, I refactored @mathwizurd's answer (to use the [`difference`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.difference) method) as follows:

```
def mode(array):
    '''
    returns a set containing valid modes
    returns a message if no valid mode exists
      - when all numbers occur the same number of times
      - when only one number occurs in the list 
      - when no number occurs in the list 
    '''
    most = max(map(array.count, array)) if array else None
    mset = set(filter(lambda x: array.count(x) == most, array))
    return mset if set(array) - mset else "list does not have a mode!"
```

These tests pass successfully:

```
mode([]) == None 
mode([1]) == None
mode([1, 1]) == None 
mode([1, 1, 2, 2]) == None
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can find mean,median and mode of a list:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

#to take input
size = int(input())
numbers = list(map(int, input().split()))

print(np.mean(numbers))
print(np.median(numbers))
print(int(stats.mode(numbers)[0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple code that finds the mode of the list without any imports:

```
nums = #your_list_goes_here
nums.sort()
counts = dict()
for i in nums:
    counts[i] = counts.get(i, 0) + 1
mode = max(counts, key=counts.get)
```

In case of multiple modes, it should return the minimum node.

Answer (score 2):

How my brain decided to do it completely from scratch. Efficient and concise :) (jk lol)

```
import random

def removeDuplicates(arr):
    dupFlag = False

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        #check if we found a dup, if so, stop
        if dupFlag:
            break

        for j in range(len(arr)):
            if ((arr[i] == arr[j]) and (i != j)):
                arr.remove(arr[j])
                dupFlag = True
                break;

    #if there was a duplicate repeat the process, this is so we can account for the changing length of the arr
    if (dupFlag):
        removeDuplicates(arr)
    else:
        #if no duplicates return the arr
        return arr

#currently returns modes and all there occurences... Need to handle dupes
def mode(arr):
    numCounts = []

    #init numCounts
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        numCounts += [0]

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        count = 1
        for j in range(len(arr)):
            if (arr[i] == arr[j] and i != j):
                count += 1
        #add the count for that number to the corresponding index
        numCounts[i] = count

    #find which has the greatest number of occurences
    greatestNum = 0
    for i in range(len(numCounts)):
        if (numCounts[i] > greatestNum):
            greatestNum = numCounts[i]

    #finally return the mode(s)
    modes = []
    for i in range(len(numCounts)):
        if numCounts[i] == greatestNum:
            modes += [arr[i]]
    
    #remove duplicates (using aliasing)
    print("modes: ", modes)
    removeDuplicates(modes)
    print("modes after removing duplicates: ", modes)
    
    return modes


def initArr(n):
    arr = []
    for i in range(n):
        arr += [random.randrange(0, n)]
    return arr

#initialize an array of random ints
arr = initArr(1000)
print(arr)
print("_______________________________________________")

modes = mode(arr)

#print result
print("Mode is: ", modes) if (len(modes) == 1) else print("Modes are: ", modes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
def print_mode (thelist):
  counts = {}
  for item in thelist:
    counts [item] = counts.get (item, 0) + 1
  maxcount = 0
  maxitem = None
  for k, v in counts.items ():
    if v > maxcount:
      maxitem = k
      maxcount = v
  if maxcount == 1:
    print "All values only appear once"
  elif counts.values().count (maxcount) > 1:
    print "List has multiple modes"
  else:
    print "Mode of list:", maxitem
```

This doesn't have a few error checks that it should have, but it will find the mode without importing any functions and will print a message if all values appear only once.  It will also detect multiple items sharing the same maximum count, although it wasn't clear if you wanted that.

Comment: So what im trying to do is to detect multiple items displaying the same count and then displaying all the items with that same count

Comment: Have you actually tried this yourself?  The extension from my code here to have it print all items with the same count is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

This will return all modes:

```
def mode(numbers)
    largestCount = 0
    modes = []
    for x in numbers:
        if x in modes:
            continue
        count = numbers.count(x)
        if count > largestCount:
            del modes[:]
            modes.append(x)
            largestCount = count
        elif count == largestCount:
            modes.append(x)
    return modes
```

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for the minimum mode, e.g:case of bi-modal distribution, using numpy.

```
import numpy as np
mode = np.argmax(np.bincount(your_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Okey!** So community has already a lot of answers and some of them used another function and you don't want.
let we create our **very simple and easily understandable** function.

```
import numpy as np

#Declare Function Name
def calculate_mode(lst):
```

> Next step is to find **Unique elements** in list and thier respective **frequency**.

```
unique_elements,freq = np.unique(lst, return_counts=True)
```

> Get **mode**

```
max_freq = np.max(freq)   #maximum frequency
mode_index = np.where(freq==max_freq)  #max freq index
mode = unique_elements[mode_index]   #get mode by index
return mode
```

> Example

```
lst =np.array([1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6])
print(calculate_mode(lst))
>>> Output [4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mode(inp_list):
    sort_list = sorted(inp_list)
    dict1 = {}
    for i in sort_list:        
            count = sort_list.count(i)
            if i not in dict1.keys():
                dict1[i] = count

    maximum = 0 #no. of occurences
    max_key = -1 #element having the most occurences

    for key in dict1:
        if(dict1[key]>maximum):
            maximum = dict1[key]
            max_key = key 
        elif(dict1[key]==maximum):
            if(key<max_key):
                maximum = dict1[key]
                max_key = key

    return max_key
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mode(data):
    lst =[]
    hgh=0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        lst.append(data.count(data[i]))
    m= max(lst)
    ml = [x for x in data if data.count(x)==m ] #to find most frequent values
    mode = []
    for x in ml: #to remove duplicates of mode
        if x not in mode:
        mode.append(x)
    return mode
print mode([1,2,2,2,2,7,7,5,5,5,5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function that gets the first mode that occurs in a list. It makes a dictionary with the list elements as keys and number of occurrences and then reads the dict values to get the mode.

```
def findMode(readList):
    numCount={}
    highestNum=0
    for i in readList:
        if i in numCount.keys(): numCount[i] += 1
        else: numCount[i] = 1
    for i in numCount.keys():
        if numCount[i] > highestNum:
            highestNum=numCount[i]
            mode=i
    if highestNum != 1: print(mode)
    elif highestNum == 1: print("All elements of list appear once.")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a clear approach, useful for classroom and only using lists and dictionaries by comprehension, you can do:

```
def mode(my_list):
    # Form a new list with the unique elements
    unique_list = sorted(list(set(my_list)))
    # Create a comprehensive dictionary with the uniques and their count
    appearance = {a:my_list.count(a) for a in unique_list} 
    # Calculate max number of appearances
    max_app = max(appearance.values())
    # Return the elements of the dictionary that appear that # of times
    return {k: v for k, v in appearance.items() if v == max_app}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#function to find mode
def mode(data):  
    modecnt=0
#for count of number appearing
    for i in range(len(data)):
        icount=data.count(data[i])
#for storing count of each number in list will be stored
        if icount>modecnt:
#the loop activates if current count if greater than the previous count 
            mode=data[i]
#here the mode of number is stored 
            modecnt=icount
#count of the appearance of number is stored
    return mode
print mode(data1)
```

Comment: You should explain your answer with comments or more details

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
def get_mode(xs):
    values, counts = np.unique(xs, return_counts=True)
    max_count_index = np.argmax(counts) #return the index with max value counts
    return values[max_count_index]
print(get_mode([1,7,2,5,3,3,8,3,2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the following.  It is O(n) and returns a list of floats (or ints).  It is thoroughly, automatically tested.  It uses collections.defaultdict, but I'd like to think you're not opposed to using that.  It can also be found at [https://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/stddev.html](https://stromberg.dnsalias.org/%7Estrombrg/stddev.html)

```
def compute_mode(list_: typing.List[float]) -> typing.List[float]:
    """                       
    Compute the mode of list_.

    Note that the return value is a list, because sometimes there is a tie for "most common value".
                                                                        
    See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797819/finding-the-mode-of-a-list
    """                                                                                                        
    if not list_:
        raise ValueError('Empty list')
    if len(list_) == 1:           
        raise ValueError('Single-element list')
    value_to_count_dict: typing.DefaultDict[float, int] = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for element in list_:
        value_to_count_dict[element] += 1
    count_to_values_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for value, count in value_to_count_dict.items():   
        count_to_values_dict[count].append(value)                           
    counts = list(count_to_values_dict)
    if len(counts) == 1:                                                                            
        raise ValueError('All elements in list are the same')          
    maximum_occurrence_count = max(counts)
    if maximum_occurrence_count == 1:
        raise ValueError('No element occurs more than once')
    minimum_occurrence_count = min(counts)
    if maximum_occurrence_count <= minimum_occurrence_count:
        raise ValueError('Maximum count not greater than minimum count')
    return count_to_values_dict[maximum_occurrence_count]
```