# Finding the mode of a list using ONLY loops and creating lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, function

I have been trying to figure out how to find the mode of a list **WITHOUT** using sorting functions nor importing any modules for quite awhile now... Here's what I have so far:

```
d = {}
def mode():
    for i in mode:
        if i in d:
            d[i] += 1
        else:
            d[i] = 1
    return
```

How do I find the output such as the following:

```
print(mode([1, 5, 6, 1, 1, 2]))
[1]
print(mode([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: mode argument is missing and name it values or sth else ... mode(values)

Comment: d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1 as a replacement for the if else block

Comment: and you need to return something

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28129716/494526

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the occurrences in your dict and extract the `max`  based on the value returning the list itself if there is no mode.

```
def mode(l):
     d= {}
    for i in l:
        d.setdefault(i, 0)
        d[i] += 1
    mx = max(d,key=d.get)
    return d[mx] if d[mx] > 1 else l
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a dictionary with the value as the key and a count as value.  If you're using Python 3, this is the Counter data type.

When you've tallied all the entries, find the max of the values.  Make a list comprehension of all elements with that value.

Comment: OP said no imports, so `collections.Counter` is out. Relatedly, `Counter` was added in 2.7, so you don't need Python 3 to have access to it.