# how to find the element in a list having most occurrence using loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, big-o

assume

```
[1,2,4,4,3,3,3]
```

and upper_limit is 8 (all numbers are not bigger than upper_limit)

how to produce 3 under the help of upper_limit
must run in O(n+upper_limit) overall time.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797819/finding-the-mode-of-a-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the mode of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797819/finding-the-mode-of-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4]
cnt = {}
most = a[0]
for x in a:
    if x not in cnt:
        cnt[x] = 0
    cnt[x] += 1
    if cnt[x] > cnt[most]:
        most = x

print(most)
```

Comment: what's the meaning of{}

Comment: @Lindadadad That means define an empty dict names cnt. An item in a dict has a key and a value. You need to add the key first before you using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [1,2,4,4,3,3,3]
counter = Counter(lst)
most_freq, freq = counter.most_common()[0]
```

Alternatives to `Counter` using dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
lst = [1,2,4,4,3,3,3]

for val in lst:
    d[val] = d[val] + 1

most_freq, freq = max(d.items(), key = lambda t: t[1])
```

---

This example keeps track of the most frequent as you iterate through circumventing the need for `max` function.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
lst = [1,2,4,4,3,3,3]
most_freq, freq = None, 0

for val in lst:
    d[val] = d[val] + 1
    if d[val] > freq:
        most_freq = val
        freq = d[val]

print(most_freq, freq)
```

---

If you don't want to use a `defaultdict` then you can just use a normal dictionary and use `dict.setdefault` instead.

```
d = {} # set d to dict
d[val] = d.setdefault(val, 0) + 1
```

Comment: Is it your contention that this is O(n)? Because I can see nothing in the docs that indicates this.

Comment: yes, btw, do you know how to code by using while loop and for loop?

Comment: You can achieve a similar thing using a dictionary, which will be `O(n  + len(dict))` the `Counter` is faster than with a dictionary but I believe it would be roughly the same.

Comment: @Lindadadad Yes, I know how to use a for loop and while loop. What about it?

Comment: Could you show me how to code with loop? i've seen many methods using collections.counter except loop! Thanks