# How Do I Program The Mode On Python 3.3.0

Tags: python, math, mode

I need help trying to program the mode in python 3.3
I've been trying for about 2 hours and it's bugging me.
Because I'm using 3.3, so we have no statistics module, which is normally how I would get around this and I can't update as its on school computers. My program Is Supposed to Calculate the Average, Median, Mode And Also Quit. They All Work Except The mode.
Anyone Have Any Ideas? It Would Help!
All I Have so Far is

```
lists = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
print("Hello! What Is Your Name?")
name = input()
func = ["Average", "Median", "Quit", "Mode"]
print("Please Enter 5 Numbers")
lists[0] = input()
lists[1] = input()
lists[2] = input()
lists[3] = input()
lists[4] = input()
print("Hello " + name + ", Would You Like " + func[0] + ", " + func[1] + ", " + func[2] + " Or, Would You Like to " + func[3]) 
func1 = input()
if func1 == "Average" :
    total = int(lists[0]) + int(lists[1]) + int(lists[2]) + int(lists[3])
    total1 = total / 4
     print("Your Average is " + str(total1))
elif func1 == "Median" :
    lists.sort()
    print("Your Median Is " + lists[2] + "!")
elif func1 == "Quit":
    print("Thank You")
elif func1 == "Mode":
```

Comment: See [Finding the mode of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797819/finding-the-mode-of-a-list)

Comment: You have an unexpected space in your line `print("Your Average is " + str(total1))`. Average function doesn't work, change to  `total1 = total / 4.`

Comment: If you have been trying for two hours, why don't you show some of your efforts? The above code doesn't even try to compute a mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the mode of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797819/finding-the-mode-of-a-list)

Comment: Homework question?

Comment: @cz it's for computer science coursework

Comment: @Nuageux What Do You Mean? The space is needed for reasons to do with concatenation. The change you've mentioned is already in the code

Comment: @Jack Space at the beginning of your line. It is not indented well.

Comment: @Nuageux I see thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following without any additional library:

```
lists = [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 7]
print(max(set(lists), key=lists.count))
```

Comment: I have just tried to do this however, it has come up as 'Invalid Syntax' And highlights max, any way around this?

Comment: oops my bad, `print` in python3 requires `()`. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks Bro! This Works!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and its method [most_common()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lists = [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 7]
>>> mode = Counter(lists).most_common(1)
>>> mode
[(2, 2)]
```