# How to print mean , median and mode in python 3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, statistics

I am new to python programming and I'm getting runtime error with my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
import statistics

tc = int(input())

while tc > 0:
    n = int(input())
    arr = input()
    l = list(map(int, arr.split(' ')))
    print("{} {} {}".format(statistics.mean(l), statistics.median(l), statistics.mode(l)))
    tc = tc - 1
```

### Error

```
StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 2 equally common values
```

### Input Format

First line consists of a single integer T denoting the number of test cases.
First line of each test case consists of a single integer N denoting the size of the array.
Following line consists of N space-separated integers Ai denoting the elements in the array.

### Output Format

For each test case, output a single line containing three-separated integers denoting the Mean, Median and Mode of the array

### Sample Input

1 
5 
1 1 2 3 3

### Sample Output

2 2 1

Comment: Could you add the error output to your question?

Comment: `StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 2 equally common values`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks. I edited the error into the question.

Comment: This is not a bug but a feuture of the `statistics.mode` function

Comment: @flevinkelming , I mentioned , i am getting Runtime Error (http://ideone.com/QAubql)

Comment: Why am I getting so many downvotes on this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a variable `mode` surrounded by a `try...except` and if `statistics` has an error get the mode a [different way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28129716/3462319).

```
try:
  mode=statistics.mode(l)
except:
  mode=max(set(l),key=l.count)
print("{} {} {}".format(statistics.mean(l), statistics.median(l), mode))
```

Comment: @KartikMadaan ....you put the try...except in the `while` loop, `l` isn't defined outside of the loop otherwise

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Kartik Madaan,**

Try this code,

## Using Python 3.X

```
import statistics
from statistics import mean,median,mode

tc = int(input())

while tc > 0:
    n = int(input())
    arr = input()
    l = list(map(int,arr.split()))
    mod = max(set(l), key=l.count)
    print(int(mean(l)),int(median(l)),mod)
    tc = tc - 1
```

I hope my answer is helpful.
If any query so comment please.

Comment: Hello kartik what you say i don't understand?

Comment: Your code gives a Compilation Error :
The errors are removed in the above link

Comment: wait one minute?

Comment: you use wrong code in  ==>ideone. please run my above code.

Comment: Invalid syntax of Print statement gives error and instead of raw_input() , you should use input()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149104/discussion-between-er-ceo-vora-mayur-and-kartik-madaan).

Comment: hello kartik because online  editor support python 3 so raw_input() not work if you use python 2 so it's work fine

Comment: Python 2 does not have statistics library