# Counting occurrences without using collections.Counter

Tags: python, counting

I am trying to retrieve the most frequent and less frequent elements in a list.

```
frequency([13,12,11,13,14,13,7,11,13,14,12,14,14])
```

My output is:

```
([7], [13, 14])
```

I tried it with:

```
import collections
s = [13,12,11,13,14,13,7,11,13,14,12,14,14]
count = collections.Counter(s)
mins = [a for a, b in count.items() if b == min(count.values())]
maxes = [a for a, b in count.items() if b == max(count.values())]
final_vals = [mins, maxes]
```

But I don't want to use the `collections` module and try a more logic oriented solution.
Can you please help me to do it without collections?

Comment: For "max occuring element" (aka. _mode_), have a look at this question: [Finding the mode of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797819/finding-the-mode-of-a-list).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the mode of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797819/finding-the-mode-of-a-list)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `try` and `except` approach with a `dict` to emulate a `Counter`.

```
def counter(it):
    counts = {}
    for item in it:
        try:
            counts[item] += 1
        except KeyError:
            counts[item] = 1
    return counts
```

or alternativly you can use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) with a default of `0`:

```
def counter(it):
    counts = {}
    for item in it:
        counts[item] = counts.get(item, 0) + 1
    return counts
```

And you should do the `min()` and `max()` outside the comprehensions to avoid repeatedly calculating that quantity (the function is now `O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)`:

```
def minimum_and_maximum_frequency(cnts):
    min_ = min(cnts.values())
    max_ = max(cnts.values())
    min_items = [k for k, cnt in cnts.items() if cnt == min_]
    max_items = [k for k, cnt in cnts.items() if cnt == max_]
    return min_items, max_items
```

This would work as expected then:

```
>>> minimum_and_maximum_frequency(counter([13,12,11,13,14,13,7,11,13,14,12,14,14]))
([7], [13, 14])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [13,12,11,13,14,13,7,11,13,14,12,14,14]
occurrences = {}
for i in data:
     if i in occurrences.keys():
             occurrences[i] += 1
     else:
             occurrences[i] = 1

max_vals = [i for i in occurrences.keys() if occurrences[i] == max(occurrences.values())]
min_vals = [i for i in occurrences.keys() if occurrences[i] == min(occurrences.values())]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = [13,12,11,13,14,13,7,11,13,14,12,14,14]

occurrences = dict()

for item in s:

    occurrences[item] = occurrences.setdefault(item, 0) + 1

mins = [a for a, b in occurrences.items() if b == min(occurrences.values())]
maxs = [a for a, b in occurrences.items() if b == max(occurrences.values())]

final_vals = [mins, maxs]
```

The `defaultdict` from `collections` is more suitable to replace `Counter` to calculate occurrences of items in list. But because you limit the use of `collections`. So the `setdefault` is more elegant to deal with `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
s = [13,12,11,13,14,13,7,11,13,14,12,14,14]
freq_low = s.count(min(s, key=s.count))
freq_high = s.count(max(s, key=s.count))
mins = [a for a in set(s) if s.count(a) == freq_low]
maxes = [a for a in set(s) if s.count(a) == freq_high]
final_vals = [mins, maxes]
```

Comment: That's `O(n^4)` (or maybe just `O(n^3)`) whereas the problem can be solved easily in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple solution, possibly not the most efficient one (?) but a simple one.

```
data = get_data()
freqs, numbers = {}, {}
for i in data:
    freqs[i] = freqs.get(i, 0) + 1
for n, c in freqs.items():
    numbers[c] = numbers.get(c, []) + [n]
counts = list(numbers.keys())
res = (numbers[min(counts)], numbers[max(counts)])
```

Let's see in detail what we have in the script above, let's start with
the example data you gave,

```
In [1]: data = [13,12,11,13,14,13,7,11,13,14,12,14,14]
```

We are going to use two dictionaries,

```
In [2]: freqs, numbers = {}, {}
```

the first one is filled iterating on `data`, its keys are the
individual numbers in `data` and its values the frequency of each
number in data (see fotnote for `freqs.get(…)`)

```
In [3]: for i in data: freqs[i] = freqs.get(i, 0) + 1
```

the second one is simply a reversal of the first one, the keys being 
the frequencies and the values being lists of numbers with a given
frequency.

```
In [4]: for n, c in freqs.items(): numbers[c] = numbers.get(c, []) + [n]

In [5]: numbers
Out[5]: {1: [7], 2: [12, 11], 4: [13, 14]}
```

At this point we need a list with the keys of `numbers`, i.e., the
occurrences

```
In [6]: counts = list(numbers.keys())
```

because we are interested in the minimum and maximum values of the
occurrences

```
In [7]: [numbers[min(counts)], numbers[max(counts)]]
Out[7]: [[7], [13, 14]]
```

---

Footnote: the `.get(key, default_value)` method of a dictionary
returns a default value if the key is not present in the dictionary,
we used this feature with a `0` default value to sum the occurrences
of individual numbers, and with `[]`, the void list, to build a list
of all the numbers with given frequency.

Comment: Maybe not the fastest one, but every step (counting, lumping and finding the extremes of keys) is `O(n)`, so the total complexity is still `O(n)` …