# Finding mode of a list

Tags: python

I'm writing a function that calculates the mode or modes of a list of numbers.

If input is `[52, 99, 37, 86, 99, 99, 99, 37, 37, 37]`, output should be `[37, 99]`. As you can see smaller number should come first, but my code won't do it. Can someone fix my code?

```
def mode(L):
    most = max(list(map(L.count, L)))
    return list(set(filter(lambda x: L.count(x) == most, L)))
```

Comment: But set is unordered. Why do you think the result _should_ be ordered?

Comment: You are loosing the order with set. Try `list(set(["b", "a"]))` to see it.

Comment: Use `Counter.most_common`, this is going to be way more efficient

Comment: @Alex I got `['b', 'a']` back. I think the order is implementation-dependent.

Comment: In case someone Googles this in the future, once Python 3.8 is out the answer becomes `import statistics; sorted(statistics.multimode(L))`

Comment: Sidenote, the `list()` in `max(list(map(L.count, L)))` is not needed.

Comment: Related: [Finding the mode of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10797819/4518341) - but not a duplicate since OP is asking about sorting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) sorts your list.

```
def mode(L):
    most = max(list(map(L.count, L)))
    return sorted(list(set(filter(lambda x: L.count(x) == most, L))))
```

**Update**
**Note:** This is a very inefficient way of calculating the mode. There are more performant solutions in other answers. This answer is focuses narrowly on what OP asked. Do not use this code in production.
Please also see notes in the comments on other improvements of this code.

Comment: You can get rid of `list()` on both lines.  They're not doing anything for you.  `max()` will consume the `map()` iterator and `sorted()` will happily consume the `set`.

Comment: Please note that the performance of this is *awful*.  Consider to do `list(map(L.count, L))` on a 10 item list `L.count()` is called 10 times and has to iterate over 10 items to make the count.  That's 100 (10*10) visits for 10 items. 10:1.  But if the list is 100 items long its 10,000 (100*100) visits.  1000:1.  So by growing the list by a factor of 10 the expense of iteration grew by a factor of 100.  That's quadratic growth.  On my computer once L becomes 10,000 items it becomes perceptively slow, while the other answers still proceed zippily along.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I agree with both of your comments -- MatthewLee you might want to consider both. However my answer was focused on the specific issue MatthewLee asked about. I have now included a note in my answer for future readers.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution is to use `collections.Counter`

```py
from collections import Counter

nums = [52, 99, 37, 86, 99, 99, 99, 37, 37, 37]

c = Counter(nums)
highest_freq = max(c.values())
mod = [n for n, freq in sorted(c.items()) if freq == highest_freq]

print(mod)
```

output:

```
[37, 99]
```

If you need only one item, you could also just use:

```
nums = [52, 99, 37, 86, 99, 99, 99, 37, 37, 37]
c = Counter(nums)
print(max(c))
```

which prints:

```
99
```

Comment: `Counter.most_common()` returns an iterator of items from highest to lowest counts.

Comment: True, but you need to specify how many you want. Selecting the most common ones (however many) requires manual iteration.

Comment: Nope.  See @WillemVanOnsem's answer.  I independently (and more slowly) came up with the same.

Comment: Still, `groupby` iterates through the list. I meant there's no straightforward solution without filtering.

Comment: No.  `groupby` creates an iterator.  It does not do the iteration.  When `next()` is called it iterates and calls the key function on the items until the return value of the key function of the iterator changes (or the iterator is exhausted).  So here in order to create the first grouping of two it consumes the first three items of `.most_common()`.  Because the count is different on the third item it groups the first two items and returns them as a group.  No further iteration of the iterator returned by `.most_common()` is done.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: `.most_common()` just does `return sorted(self.items(), key=_itemgetter(1), reverse=True)` so I think my point is an empty one.

Answer (score 3):

You here make it computationally quite expensive. A `.count(..)` takes linear time, making this algorithm quadratic.

You can make use of a `Counter` here to perform a single pass over the list, and then obtain the most common elements, like:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

def mode(L):
    _, common = next(groupby(Counter(L).most_common(), itemgetter(1)))
    return sorted(map(itemgetter(0), common))
```

Given the elements in the list can be hashed effectively, this will run in linear time.

Comment: In case someone Googles this in the future, once Python 3.8 is out the answer becomes `import statistics; sorted(statistics.multimode(L))`