# Optimizing Python Code for returning the smallest element with highest occurrences in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I am trying to solve one of HackerRanks easy rated problems with Python. My code solves 4 out of 5 test cases but for one of the test cases, I get an error message saying time limit exceeded. Please recommend ways to optimize this. I am a beginner at python and still trying to understand itertools but it seems quite complicated.

Problem Statement:
Given an array of bird sightings where every element represents a bird type id, determine the id of the most frequently sighted type. If more than 1 type has been spotted that maximum amount, return the smallest of their ids.

Sample input: arr=[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,3,4]
Sample output: 3

My current code:

```
def migratoryBirds(arr):
    d={}
    arr2=[]
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        d[arr[i]]=arr.count(arr[i])
    for i in d.keys():
        if d[i]==max(d.values()):
            arr2.append(i)
    return(min(arr2))
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question might belong to another Stack site - [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797819/finding-the-mode-of-a-list) might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

```python
def migratoryBirds(arr):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    most_common_item = max(arr, key=arr.count)           
    print(most_common_item)


migratoryBirds([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4]) # Testing
```

Comment: You should include what you expect the output to be. "smallest element with highest occurrences"  I think you mean, the highest frequency is 3, both 3 and 4 occur 3 times. Then the answer is 3 because that is the smallest number with the maximum occurrence?

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is slower because you are going through the whole array multiple times with the `.count()` function. You are also going through your dictionary multiple times in the second loop with the max() function.  This results in O(N^2) time complexity.

To achieve O(N) time, you should only add 1 per item in the array and then process the dictionary on the basis of max total / min id:

```
arr=[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,3,4]

counts = {}
for bird in arr: counts[bird] = counts.get(bird,0) + 1      # +1 per bird
result,_ = max(counts.items(),key=lambda kv:(kv[1],-kv[0])) # max total / min id

print(result) # 3
```

Comment: `collections.Counter` would be even simpler: you can just give it a sequence and it'll compute the counts.

Comment: @Masklinn, indeed but I needed to illustrate my point about only adding 1 per bird rather than calling sum() each time.  Counter would have abstracted part that too much.

Answer (score -1):

I am a new entry too in python!
I solved like that...maybe this was not the scope of the exercise and probably this will be the worst code you have ever seen running...but it runs! :D

```
arr=[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,3,4]

import pandas as pd
a=pd.Series(arr)

x=a.value_counts()==a.value_counts().max()
print( x[x].tail(1).index[0] )
```