# How do we find mode and number of occurrences of that mode in python?

Tags: python, arrays

In an array `[1,2,2,3]` the mode is 2 and it occurs two times. How to get this as output for a particular array?

Comment: What do you mean by mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the mode of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797819/finding-the-mode-of-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `collections` module form python and call in a `counter` for maximum occurrence of a number.

```
from collections import Counter
sample = [10, 10, 30, 10, 50, 30, 60]
print("Mode of List A is % s" % (Counter(sample).most_common(1)[0][0]))
```

If you are not relying much on the concept of how it is built, the easier way is to use the `statistics` module and get the mode.

Example:

```
from statistics import mode

sample=[1,2,2,2,3,4]
print(mode(sample))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways... But I guess the best one is:

Defining a function like:

```
def DuplicatesCheck(input_array):   
    for el in input_array:
        if input_array.count(el) > 1:
            return True
    return False
```

Then call it this way:

```
your_array = [1,2,2,3]
result = DuplicatesCheck(your_array)
if result:
    print('Positive')
else:
    print('Negative')
```