# How do I find the mode of a list of numbers?

Tags: python

I am trying to achieve this without the use of external libraries. If anyone could help me out with this and include a bit of an explanation that would be greatly appreciated.

```py
def mode(list):
     dictionary= {}
    for i in list:
        dictionary.setdefault(i, 0)
        dictionary[i] += 1
    maximum = max(dictionary,key=dictionary.get)
```

Comment: You can find the frequency of each number and the number with highest frequency will be the mode.

Comment: The code you wrote looks mostly fine (apart from using `list` as an argument name), but you should `return max(dictionary, key=dictionary.get)` instead of assigning it to a variable that you never use.

Comment: Please refer to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797819/finding-the-mode-of-a-list)

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have?

Comment: Are you asking how to use `return` in python?

Comment: I completely missed return haha. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a naive (non-optimal but very simple) solution using `max` and `count`:

```
>>> def mode(nums):
...     return max(nums, key=nums.count)
...
>>> mode([1, 2, 3, 3, 4])
3
```

The more efficient solution (because it doesn't require iterating over `nums` once per item in `nums`) is indeed to use a counter.  Your code mostly does this, but doesn't actually return the result:

```
>>> def mode(nums):
...     counter = {}
...     for i in nums:
...         counter[i] = counter.get(i, 0) + 1
...     return max(counter, key=counter.get)
...
>>> mode([1, 2, 3, 3, 4])
3
```

Note that the `statistics` module is built into Python (i.e. it is not an external library) and it contains a `mode` function:

```
>>> from statistics import mode
>>> mode([1, 2, 3, 3, 4])
3
```