# Python: return value with higher percentage of appearance in nested list

Tags: python

I have a nested list of entries with single numeric values, and I need to determine which value has the higher percentage of appearance in total.

```
[['3', '7', '13', '4'],
 ['7', '3', '2', '1', '13', '4'],
 ['3', '13'],
 ['3', '7', '4', '13'],
 ['7', '3', '13', '4'],
 ['3', '13', '7', '8', '4'],
 ['1', '7', '3', '4', '13'],
 ['13'],
 ['7', '3', '13'],
 ['7', '3', '4']]
```

In this example, the number '13' appears in 90% of the entries.

I know I could iterate over each entry, using a counter and comparing the results at the end but there should be a cleaner way to do this.

Any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can a single number appear more than once in a single entry? For example, is `['3', '7', '3', '13']` possible?

Comment: Are the entries in your list supposed to be numbers (`int`'s) or are they represented as strings (`str`)?

Comment: @Robᵩ each number appears only once.

Comment: Just a hint... dictionaries are you friend...

Comment: @Hooked they're included as strings since they're extracted from LDAP. I could convert them to ints (with map(), I think) if that makes things easier.

Comment: check this post:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/python-most-common-element-in-a-list][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/python-most-common-element-in-a-list

Comment: @KobiK Thanks for the link, it's not the first time I ask something already answered in another thread only with different words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flatten the list and count numbers (be sure to not allow repeated numbers in sublists, otherwise convert them to sets first)

```
>>> c = collections.Counter(item for sublist in data for item in sublist)
>>> c
Counter({'13': 9, '3': 9, '7': 8, '4': 7, '1': 2, '8': 1, '2': 1})
>>> c.most_common(1)[0]
('13', 9)
```

Now divide 9 by the size of your data (10) = 0,9 = 90%

Also note that `3` would be a valid match as well.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
items = [['3', '7', '13', '4'],
 ['7', '3', '2', '1', '13', '4'],
 ['3', '13'],
 ['3', '7', '4', '13'],
 ['7', '3', '13', '4'],
 ['3', '13', '7', '8', '4'],
 ['1', '7', '3', '4', '13'],
 ['13'],
 ['7', '3', '13'],
 ['7', '3', '4']]

from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
print Counter(chain.from_iterable(items)).most_common(1)[0]
# 13, 9
```

Comment: You are hiding something (that may be important to the OP) here. The fact that you take a single element `[0]` from your Counter implies that there may be more than one match. Indeed, `(3,9)` is also a correct solution.