# Python list maximum occurrences with if

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python and I need to find the maximum occurrence of a number in a list if the number is above the average of the list.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks,

John.

Comment: Compute the average, and then loop through the list seeing what's bigger than the average. If you want more details than that, you should post what you've attempted so far/where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Counter` like this

```
x = [1,2,4,3,2,2,4]
avg = sum(x)/len(x)
from collections import Counter
print [(num, count) for num, count in Counter(x).most_common() if num > avg]
```

**Output**

```
[(4, 2), (3, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520716/98191 to find the most common list item:

```
foo = [1,8,8,4,5,6,7,8]

from itertools import groupby as g
def most_common_oneliner(L):
    return max(g(sorted(L)), key=lambda(x, v):(len(list(v)),-L.index(x)))[0]

top = most_common_oneliner(foo)

if top >= max(foo):
    print top
```

Comment: The asker wants the code to behave in such a way that if the most common value is not above the average of the numbers, then the next most common value is considered, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The following will output a tuple (count, element) where element is greater than the average of the list:

```
x = [1,2,4,3,2,2,4]

print reduce(max, [(x.count(i), i) or i in x if i > sum(x)/len(x)])

#prints (2,4)
```

Saving the average instead of computing it each time is a better option.