# How do I find the mode of a list or tuple without the frequency?

Tags: python, collections, counter, mode

I'm trying to find the most occurring number in a tuple and assign that value to a variable. I tried the following code, but it gives me the frequency and the mode, when I only need the mode.

```
from collections import Counter
self.mode_counter = Counter(self.numbers)
self.mode = self.mode_counter.most_common(1)

print self.mode
```

Is there a way to just assign the mode to self.mode using Counter?

Comment: Here's an answer for a similar question with interesting soluitions: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/python-most-common-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`most_common(1)` returns a list of 1 tuple.

You have two possibilities:

Use 
`self.mode, _ = self.mode_counter.most_common(1)[0]` to discard the second value

Use `self.mode = self.mode_counter.most_common(1)[0][0]` to only get the first value

Answer (score 4):

Just unpack the return value of `most_common`.

```
[(mode, _)] = mode_counter.most_common(1)
```

Comment: Why the `[]` on the left hand side?

Comment: Stumped me at first, too. The result is a list of tuples.

Comment: @JakobBowyer print `mode_counter.most_common()` to see the intuition.

Comment: Cute. Ill remember that next time