# Python getting the key of the highest value in dictionary, without using inbuilt functions

Tags: python, dictionary

How should we get the ***key of the highest value*** in python dictionary without using a inbuilt functions

```
{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 3, 5: 2} **Expecting answer to be 4**
```

This can be easily done by

```
max_key = max(check, key=lambda k: check[k])
```

But wanted to try without builtin function(without max, lambda)

Any help is much appreciated

**my full code**

```
def array(num):
    check={}
    for i in range(len(num)):
        if num[i] in check:
            check[num[i]]+=1
        else:check[num[i]]=1

    max_key = max(check, key=lambda k: check[k])



array([1,2,3,4,5,4,5,4])
```

Comment: Can you show your code for this for what you have attempted already?

Comment: Loop over all the entries, keep track of the maximum

Comment: FYI, the case you describe is better covered by `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Having a list named `num` is a confusing variable name

Comment: @idjaw...I have revised...help in getting the highest key value

Comment: @idjaw Return the most frequently occurring element from the list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python most common element in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/python-most-common-element-in-a-list)

Comment: "lambda" is not a built-in function. It is a keyword used to define one-line functions out of an evaluating expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function below perform simple loop thought dictionary and return biggest value of key **without any builtins**:

```
def get_max_val_key(data):
    max_value = None
    for key in data:
        if max_value is None or max_value < data[key]:
            max_value = data[key]
            max_key = key
    return max_key



data = {'a':11, 'b':12}
print(get_max_val_key(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
data= {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 3, 5: 2}
maxVal= None
maxKey= -1
for k in data:
    if maxVal is None or maxVal< data[k]:
        maxVal= data[k]
        maxKey= k
```

Comment: I believe iteritems() is also a inbuilt function..right?.......correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: What if all elements of the list are less than -1?

Comment: This solution wont work if you get a key with lower value for the same value field.

Comment: that approach assumes your dictionary values can be compared to ints, and that there's no negative keys, ever. Use -float("inf") as first value instead to solve the second problem.

Comment: @spidy: Yes, `iteritems()` is an in-built function. Let me edit.

Comment: @Himanshu....I wanted answer without inbuilt function..........please check the question

Comment: @spidy: Edited. Please check.

Comment: @spidy: Sorry, edited again. And it has now become exactly same as the accepted solution! :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
score_card = {
    "James": 65,
    "William": 78,
    "Steven": 59,
    "Jason": 82,
    "Keith": 80
}


def highest_score(score_card):
  best = 0
  name = ""
  for player in score_card:
    score = score_card[player]
    if score > best:
      best= score
      name = player
   print(f"Highest Score is {best} by {name}")

highest_score(score_card)
```

**Output:** Highest Score is 82 by Jason