# Find most common element

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I print the most common element of a list without importing a library?

```
l=[1,2,3,4,4,4]
```

So I want the output to be `4`.

Comment: I'm brand-new here,i've not get used to this type of asking.I'm sorry.Could you please answer my question?

Comment: No. Because **this isn't a code-writing service**. Learn [ask], and actually put in some effort yourself before dumping it on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python most common element in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/python-most-common-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the unique values first:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
s = set(l)
```

then you can create list of (occurrences, value) tuples

```
freq = [(l.count(i), i) for i in s]  # [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4)]
```

get the "biggest" element (biggest number of occurrences, the biggest value if there are more than one with the same number of occurrences):

```
result = max(freq)  # (3, 4)
```

and print the value:

```
print(result[1])  # 4
```

or as a "one-liner" way:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
print(max((l.count(i), i) for i in set(l))[1])  # 4
```

Comment: `max((l.count(i), i) for i in set(l))[1]`, no need to check extra values using range.

Comment: Yes absolutely, thanks for making the code better and your explanations.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst=[1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6]
from collections import Counter
Counter(lst).most_common(1)[0]
```

`Counter(lst)` returns a `dict` of element-occurence pairs. `most_common(n)` returns the n most common elements from the dict, along with the number of occurences.

Comment: OP stipulated "without importing a library" (for some reason)

Comment: I do not want to import a library.