# Pandas: quick glance at column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge dataset with 1000+ columns. Most of them contains *NaN's * or just a few values. Manual sifting through each column is an unreasonable waste of time. How can I do an estimate column diversity, top freq values, etc with a single command?

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.describe()` is featured very early on in the introductory text of pandas' documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html as is counting unique values: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#histogramming

Comment: What do you mean by "few" values? 
Do you expect discrete repeated values or floats?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get what single column contains, so you can make a for loop like that:

```
column = [array[i] for i in range(0,len(array), STEP]
```

where STEP = the number of columns in your file

Then you can do whatever you want with that. Answering to your questions,
you can use i.e. `max(column) - min(column)`, that will give you diversity.
To get top common values I suggest you look there:

[click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/python-most-common-element-in-a-list)

Comment: this is pretty inefficient compared to `dataframe.describe()`