# Find the most frequently occurring digit in a list

Tags: python, counting

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Compose a function that takes a list of single digits (entered at
>   the command-line when running the program) and find the digit entered most frequently.

For example, the following command:

```
$ python frequency.py 4 6 7 7 0 5 9 9 4 9 8 3 3 3 3
```

Should return 3 as the result

I figured I could solve this problem using a recursive function and a for loop, but my attempt is not providing the correct result.

```
def frequency2(a):
    a[0:1] = []
    b = a
    if a == []:
        return []
    else:
        return [[a[0]] + [b.count(a[0])]] + frequency2(a[1:])

aa = sys.argv

print frequency2(aa)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python most common element in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/python-most-common-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) and simply pass in `sys.argv`:

#### frequency.py file:

```
import collections
import sys

print(collections.Counter(sys.argv).most_common(1)[0][0])
```

This gives a correct answer when called from the command line:

```
$ python frequency.py 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 1 2 1
1
```

---

> What am I doing wrong?

You do build a list of values and counts but you don't make any attempt to get the maximum of it. You could for example use `max` with a `key` (because you want the maximum count) after calling the `frequency` function. Just change your last line to:

```
print(max(frequency2(aa), key=lambda x: x[1])[0])
```

The `[0]` is to get the actual item of the item-frequency sublist.

Comment: I did not expect to get such an explanatory and instructive answer. Thank you so much! And also thank you for teaching "key" usage.