# Python Most Common values in a List

Tags: python, list

I need a function that returns the most common values from a list. If there is more than one most common value, return all of them.

```
l = [1, 1, 2, 2, 4]

def most_common(l):
    #some code 
    return common
```

This should return:

```
[1, 2]
```

Since they both appear twice.

I am surprised there is no simple function for this. I have tried collections but can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: I don't see your "I tried but it didn't work" code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python most common element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/python-most-common-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first group items in a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with counts as the values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [1, 1, 2, 2, 4]

counts = defaultdict(int)
for number in l:
    counts[number] += 1

print(counts)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 2, 2: 2, 4: 1})
```

Then you could find the most common values from this dictionary:

```
most_common = [k for k, v in counts.items() if v == max(counts.values())]

print(most_common)
# [1, 2]
```

Comment: Nifty! This definitely needs more upvotes.