# How to find equal most common values in a list together with count

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of interger:

```
A = [1,2,3,5,2,3]
B = [1,2,3,5,2,3,5]
```

I want to use most_common to get the top same count like this: `[(2, 2), (3, 2)]` for the list `A` and `[(2, 2), (3, 2), (5, 2)]` for the list `B`. How can I do this?

Comment: Any attempts from your side? You should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe, why your attempts failed.

Comment: Related: [Finding the single most common element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/find-the-most-common-element-in-a-list)

Comment: @Aran-Fey: I have read your post before but couldn't find the answer

Comment: @Aran-Fey I deleted my answer, don't know what to say : |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One inefficient way is to use `collections.Counter` followed by a dictionary comprehension. Remember that `Counter` returns a dictionary, which can be manipulated like any other.

### Counter

```
from collections import Counter

A_c = Counter(A)
B_c = Counter(B)

max_val = max(A_c.values())
A_res = [(k, v) for k, v in A_c.items() if v == max_val]
# [(2, 2), (3, 2)]

max_val = max(B_c.values())
B_res = [(k, v) for k, v in B_c.items() if v == max_val]
# [(2, 2), (3, 2), (5, 2)]
```

### numpy.unique

A more efficient solution is available via 3rd party library `numpy`. Here you benefit from holding counts in contiguous memory blocks.

```
import numpy as np

def max_counter(lst):
    values, counts = np.unique(lst, return_counts=True)
    idx = np.where(counts == counts.max())[0]
    return list(zip(values[idx], counts[idx]))
```

### Counter + groupby

A third solution combines `itertools.groupby` with `collections.Counter`. You should test to see which method is suitable and efficient for your data.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def max_counter_grp(lst):
    grouper = groupby(Counter(lst).most_common(), key=itemgetter(1))
    return max((list(j) for _, j in grouper), key=lambda x: x[0][1])
```