# Python : most frequent element (mode) of sorted list without use any fonction

Tags: python, list, mode

I went around many forums without finding my solution because most uses at least one pre-function.

I must return the statistical mode of a sorted list. Warning, because I can't use any function, like:  Max, Count, key, set.

My function be in o(n)

I try with my own fonction :

```
def mode_liste (lis_resultat):
    """lis_resultat: sorted list"""

    d=0
    e=0
    for i in range (len(lis_resultat)-1,1,-1):
        if (lis_resultat[i]==lis_resultat[i-1]):
            e+=1
        else:
            if (d<=e):
                res=lis_resultat[i-1]
                d=e
                e=0
    return res
```

But this function don't work with a list of less than 2 items, and I know that it's not the good solution

Comment: You can probably find a solution here: [Find the most common element in a list](//stackoverflow.com/q/1518522)

Comment: I read this forum but each of the proposed functions use functions like "max, sorted, or count, etc..." and I can't use this function because we have not learned it yet in school ...

Comment: Did you scroll far enough to find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1519293/1222951)?

Comment: Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2634155/1222951).

Comment: [Another one.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1518542/1222951)

Comment: @Aran-Fey: That last linked answer is `O(n**2)`, but your other links are good.

Comment: no because I have not learned yet: " {}", or "key", or "try" but it's good I had an answer that works and with that things I learned. thank you for your answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution with lis being the list operated upon:

```
counter = 0
my_max = 0
max_index = 0

if len(lis) == 1:
    my_max = 1
    max_index = 0
else:
    for i in range(1,len(lis)):
        if lis[i] == lis[i-1]:
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter = 1
        if counter > my_max:
            my_max = counter
            max_index = i

print(f"occurences: {my_max},mode: {lis[max_index]}")
```