# Saving a value, removing it and then running again with the rest of a list

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, tuples

### Problem Description

I am firstly I am having a list of values like:

```
(1,2,3,1,3,2,2,2,1)
```

What I want to achieve is :

1. Find the most common one (working).
2. Delete it from the list (working).
3. Repeat the same thing for the remaining values in the list.

**For instance**

Taking this Tuple:

```
(1,2,3,1,3,2,2,2,1)
```

Store that 2 is the most common int, then

```
(1,3,3,1,1,)
```

Store that 1 is the **second**  most common int, then

```
(3,3)
```

Store that 2 is the **third**  most common int, then

---

### My source Code

**NOTE  lets say that `self.final_votes` would be  (1,2,3,1,3,2,2,2,1)**

```
def erase_common(self):
        possitions = []
        counter = 0
        common = self.final_votes[0] 
      
        
        for i in self.final_votes:
            cand_freq = self.final_votes.count(i) 
            if(cand_freq> counter): 
                counter = cand_freq
                common = i
        
         possitions.append(common)
         while common in self.final_votes:
         self.final_votes.remove(common)
```

this is the whole code

```
class voting_system:
    def __init__(self):
        #self.tutor_group = self.get_tutor_group()
        self.stud_num = self.get_stud_num()
        self.cand_num = self.get_cand_num()
        self.cand_name = self.get_cand_name()
        self.final_votes = self.ind_votes()
        self.erase_common()
        
#     def get_tutor_group(self):
#         tutor_groups = ("7A","7B","7C","7D","7E","7F","8A","8B","8C","8D","8E","8F","9A","9B","9C","9D","9E","9E",
#                     "9F","10A","10B","10C","10D","10E","10F","11A","11B","11C","11D","11E","11F")
# 
#         flag = True
#         while flag == True:
#             try:
#                 self.tutor_group = input("please enter the tutor group: ")
#                 if self.tutor_group not in tutor_groups:
#                     raise ValueError("Tutor group entred doesn't exist")
#             except ValueError as error:
#                 print(error)
#                 flag = True
#                     
#             else:
#                 flag = False
        
#        return self.tutor_group
        
    def get_stud_num(self):
#         flag = True
#         while flag == True:
#             try:
#                 self.stud_num = int(input("Please enter number of students: "))
#                 if self.stud_num<0 or self.stud_num>35:
#                     raise ValueError("NUMBER OF STUDENTS INVALID")
#             except ValueError as error:
#                 print(error)
#                 flag = True
#                 
#             else:
#                 flag = False
        self.stud_num = 7
        return self.stud_num
        
            
    def get_cand_num(self):
#         flag = True
#         while flag == True:
#             try:
#                 self.cand_num = int(input("Please enter number of candidates: "))
#                 if self.cand_num>4:
#                     raise ValueError("NUMBER OF CANDIDATES INVALID")
#             except ValueError as error:
#                 print(error)
#                 flag = True
#                 
#             else:
#                 flag = False
        self.cand_num = 3
        return self.cand_num
        
    
    def get_cand_name(self):
        self.cand_name = []
        for i in range(self.cand_num):
            candidate = input("Enter candidate name: ")
            self.cand_name.append(candidate)
        return self.cand_name
    
    def print_cands(self):
        for i in range(len(self.cand_name)):
            print(i+1, " : ", self.cand_name[i])
            
            
    def ind_votes(self):
        self.final_votes = []
        self.print_cands()
        abs_vote = 0
        
        flag = True
        while flag == True:
            try:
                for i in range(self.stud_num): 
                    vote = input("To vote type 'V' and the candidates number, to abstent type 'A': ")
                    if vote.isalpha() == True:
                        abs_vote +=1
                    else:
                        self.final_votes.append(vote[1])
            
                    if vote[1] > str(self.cand_num):
                        raise ValueError("VOTED CANDIDATE NONEXISTENT")
            except ValueError as error:
                print(error)
                flag = True
            else:
                flag = False
               
                
        return self.final_votes
        return abs_vote

    def erase_common(self):
        possitions = []
        counter = 0
        common = self.final_votes[0] 
      
        
        for i in self.final_votes:
            cand_freq = self.final_votes.count(i) 
            if(cand_freq> counter): 
                counter = cand_freq
                common = i
        
         possitions.append(common)
         while common in self.final_votes:
         self.final_votes.remove(common)            
        
        
                    
run = voting_system()
```

any suggestions would be appreciated:)

Comment: Your post code is incomplete - it seems that you have written a `class` - guessing by `self.final_votes`?   Can you post complete code?  And what's the `ending condition` for the repeated checking  - eg. until the last number is `n` count?

Comment: the fucntion should stop once there are no more elements in the list, I'll post the code :).

Comment: If that's the case - what's the goal of this program then?  Just an exercise?    `No more elements in the list` == `empty list`?   Miss the point here...

Comment: It is a exam asignment, its basicallz responsible for deciding the winners of a class vote, this part finds the largest amount of votes with the candidate's name, erases it, does it again for the others

Comment: and because the amount of candidates is variable, I cant hard code it

Comment: What if the final list is '[1, 3]' a 'tie'?

Comment: yea I haven't done that feature yet, I firstly wanted to have this functioning and then focus on the tie feature

Comment: @Elloder may you add or explain what is the **expected output** and what you get now instead? And what is wrong in more specific with your code? Or you want to see a better implementation of it?

Comment: Okay so bassically the smaller portion of the code is supposed to take the list then it counts what candidate number is the most common, eg candidate number 1, it saves that candidate number 1 had the most votes and erases his votes from the list, this is the part that works.

Comment: What is left is a list without the votes from candidate 1, eg before erasion it looked like 1,1,2,3,2,3,1,3,2,1,1,2 after erasion it looks like 2,3,2,3,2,2.Now what I need, is for the same thing to happen again, but to the second most commonly voted candidate, at the end there should be a array, with their positions, for example candidate @ had most votes - he is first, candidate 3 had second most votes so he is second and so on.

Comment: basically i need it to spit out their order, like [1,2,3] or [3,1,2] ..., the problem is that I cant simply have 3 separate blocks to do this, because the number of candidates is from 1 to 4, so I NEED SOME SORT OF UPDATING LOOP

Comment: @Elloder makes sense and should be pretty easy to do, more easy to do than explain it. If no one answer before I would give it a go but make take me sometimes later as Im' currently not on.

Comment: Ok thanks Federico, I can probably imagine that solution is pretty simple but my brain is a bit overcooked, I'll try a bit :)

Comment: @Elloder I've posted one solution, does this answer your question?

Comment: Hi federico, thanks a bunch I actually came up with my own solution, but yours is much more elegant so thanks:). Can you just explain what is going on? BTW huge appreciation for your time :) have an awesome day

Comment: @Elloder I'm glad it helped. Basically Groupby and Counter are both algorithms and function that are within the Python Standard Library. I added the link where you can found documentation and inplementation of it, explaint it is bit difficult. They are highly efficient function.

Comment: @Elloder if my answer helped you and solved the problem I suggest you to mark it as accepted so it can be removed from the queue, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Easier and probably the best:

User Python Counter from Collection.

```py
from collections import Counter


final_votes = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1]

def erase_common(votes):
    count_votes = Counter(votes)
    return count_votes.most_common()

print(erase_common(final_votes)) # [(2, 4), (1, 3), (3, 2)]
votes = erase_common(final_votes)
for idx, votes in enumerate(votes):
    print(f'{idx+1}) Vote {votes[0]} Total = {votes[1]}')
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
1) Vote 2 Total = 4
2) Vote 1 Total = 3
3) Vote 3 Total = 2
```

---

### Using groupby

@AlexMartelli has a really good answer regarding find most common element on list --> [Find the most common element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/find-the-most-common-element-in-a-list)

So you can implement this by doing this:

```py
from itertools import groupby


final_votes = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1]

def most_common_oneliner(L):
    grupped = groupby(sorted(L))
    result = {group: len([*scores]) for group, scores in grupped}
    final_sorted_votes = []
    while result:
        max = [(0, 0)]
        for score, res in result.items():
            if max[0][1] < res:
                max[0] = (score, res)
        del result[max[0][0]]
        final_sorted_votes += max

    return final_sorted_votes


result = most_common_oneliner(final_votes)

for idx, votes in enumerate(result):
    print(f'{idx+1}) Vote {votes[0]} Total = {votes[1]}')
```

### Documentation

- [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
- [Counter Implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L516)
- [most_common function inplementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L600)
- [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
- [how-do-i-use-itertools-groupby Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-itertools-groupby)
- [geeksforgeeks.org | python-find-most-frequent-element-in-a-list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find-most-frequent-element-in-a-list/)