# 10 most occuring element in a list-python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider a list with 100 elements. I want to write a code to print 10 most occuring element.

```
import itertools
import operator

def most_common(lst):
    return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)
```

THis is giving me the 1st most occuring element. I want 10 most occuring.

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/find-the-most-common-element-in-a-list

Comment: this is a list of IP addreses and i want to return 10 most occurning IP addreses

Comment: As an aside, `max(set(lst), key=lst.count)` is an inefficient algorithm

Answer (score 2):

For calculating frequencies of hashable objects, Counter is great in python:

```
from collections import Counter

my_list = ['a','b','c','a','a','b','c','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','c','b','c','b','c','d','d','d','d','d']

freqs= Counter(my_list)
print(freqs.most_common(3))
```

**Output**

```
[('a', 11), ('b', 5), ('c', 5)]
```

In your case, you would substitute 3 in the parameters of most_common() function with the desired number of elements, which is 10.

Comment: This only works for hashable objects.

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner OPs too, it uses `set`

Comment: In this case, IP addresses are strings which are hashable