# More Efficient Ways of Returning Most Common Element of a List

Tags: python, list, algorithm

Suppose we have the following code:

```
import random
num_samples = 1000
a = list(random.randint(0,9) for _ in range(num_samples))

#sample(a, num_samples if len(a) > num_samples else len(a))
def most_common(lst):
    return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)

most = most_common(a)
print(most)
```

Is there a faster way of getting the most common element of a list?

Comment: `Counter` from `collections` is very heavily optimized for such operations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/find-the-most-common-element-in-a-list

Comment: Does this answer your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the most common element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/find-the-most-common-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (it will do the job for you)

```
import random
from collections import Counter

num_samples = 1000
a = list(random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(num_samples))


# sample(a, num_samples if len(a) > num_samples else len(a))
def most_common(lst):
    return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)


most = most_common(a)
print(most)

counter = Counter(a)
print(counter.most_common(1))
```

Comment: wow I never new there was a faster way than using max()

Comment: @balderman: Thanks! If you get an output like this `[('"apple"', 200)]`, It might be cumbersome to access the first element `"apple"` . Otherwise I like this answer.

Comment: @Theshape the issue isn't using `max`, in fact, here you really should use `max(counter.items())`, which will be faster than `most_common`, the key here is you are avoiding the *highly inefficient* `max(a, key=list.count)`. Using `list.count` in a loop like that forces you into a quadratic time algorithm, when this should be able to be done in linear time (i.e. by using a counter).