# max on collections.Counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-collections

The max on `collections.Counter` is counter intuitive, I want to find the find the character that occurs the most in a string.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter('aaaabbbcc')
>>> max(c)
'c'
>>> c
Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 2})
```

I know I should be using `most_common`, but its use seems contrived.

```
>>> c.most_common(1)[0][0]
'a'
```

Is there a case for supporting max on Counter ?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/find-the-most-common-element-in-a-list?

Comment: `max` accepts *any iterable*. `Counter` objects are `dict` objects, Iterating over a dict iterates over its keys.

Comment: I like the counter as it can be easily updated and viewed, but yes that answers solves this specific question.

Comment: @DataCyclist that question isn't really relevant to yours, that quesiton was asking how to efficiently get the most common item in a collection of *unhashable items*. You should definitely use a `Counter`, and you can just use `max(Counter(data).items(), key=lambda x:x[-1])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this way is actually slower as it requires to build the `items` tuple

Comment: @mozway it is *definitely faster* than the solution in the linked duplicate

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes of course, using `count` more than once is already a waste, I was comparing to my answer and OP's original solution ;)

Comment: @mozway I don't think it will be slower than `max((c := Counter(s)), key=c.get)` it's pretty much doing the exact same thing. In fact, your way forces you to check the dictionary with a hash-based lookup, whereas relying on the built-in iterators is probably faster, but both would be pretty similar

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's ~1.5-2× slower, that's why I comented ;) (NB. I used `max(c.items(), key=lambda x:x[-1])` vs `max(c, key=c.get)` to compare only the max, not assignment of the counts)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `key` parameter of `max`:

```
max(c, key=c.get)
```

output: `'a'`

*NB. `Counter.most_common` performs sorting, so using `max` this way should also be faster (a quick test tells me this is the case on small Counters while there is limited difference on large Counters).*

Comment: This is partially incorrect most_common only sorts when `n is None` otherwise it uses a heap, but the heap documentation suggest using max when `n = 1`

Comment: @Dani that's true, thanks for the comment ;)

Comment: Won't it provide an answer even if there is no max? (return the first element, I think)

Comment: @camelBack yes this is the defined behavior and `Counter.most_common` would also return the first element in case of a tie.

Answer (score 0):

max with key seems to be faster than most_common

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import timeit

>>> s0 = 'aaaabbbcc'
>>> s1 = s0[:] * 100

>>> def f_max(s): return max((c := Counter(s)), key=c.get)
>>> def f_common(s): return Counter(s).most_common(1)[0][0]

>>> timeit.repeat("f_max(s1)", "from __main__ import f_max, f_common, s1", number=10000)
[0.32935670800000594, 0.32097511900002473, 0.3285609399999885, 0.3300831690000052, 0.326068628999991]

>>> timeit.repeat("f_common(s1)", "from __main__ import f_max, f_common, s1", number=10000)
[0.3436732490000054, 0.3355550489999928, 0.34284031400000003, 0.343095218000002, 0.34329394300002036]
>>>
```

Comment: As mentioned in my answer this is true for a small number of keys, not anymore when there are many keys (which is not the case in your example there are only a/b/c), in this case both are equally fast ;)