# How to get the most common in a list of strings

Tags: python

So i have a response from an api (openweathermap.org) and i have all the {weather} variables in a list. I am trying to get the most common in ["Sunny", "Scattered clouds", "Rainy", "Scattered Clouds"] Just an example but something like that.

I also thought of a way using for loops and dictionaries:

```
listt = ["R","S","SC","SC"]
dictt = {}
for i in listt:
    dict[f"{i}"] +=1
```

But... Yeah. I know it would not work. I mean, i could hard code `dictt` but i dont know all the weather conditions from the API.
Is there another way to get the most common String in a list?

i am using one-call api from openweathermap.org

Comment: Not sure if i get i right but if you want to know which is the most occuring weather type from the list you can use collections an eg ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item

Comment: You can use the `Counter` type found in the standard `collections` library. It has a method called `.most_common()` . https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects

Comment: Please be aware that ``dict[f"{i}"]`` is just ``dict[i]``.

Comment: This is your exact answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59246517/13202252

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Solution

###### (Tested in Python 2 and 3)

You could use a dictionary to map the values like what you provided.

Then to get the key or most common string in the dictionary, get the key of the maximum value in the dictionary, like this: [(Reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)

```
listt = ["R","S","SC","SC"]
dictt = {}

for i in listt:
    # add to dictionary if it does not exist
    if i not in dictt:
        # this also does the same thing as 'dict[f"{i}"]' 
        dictt[i] = 1

    # update dictionary
    else:
        dictt[i] +=1

print(max(dictt))
# 'SC'
```

---

### Other Remarks

- ###### Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/find-the-most-common-element-in-a-list/59246517#59246517) as commented by @Fareed Khan
- You can also utilize Counters in python (as commented by @Ederic Oytas)

```
from collections import Counter

listt = ["R","S","SC","SC"]
print(max(Counter(listt)))
# 'SC'
```

Comment: This does not fix any of the errors in the question code. It has at least a name and a key error.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi apologies, just found out the error. 'dictt' is a confusing variable name :D

Comment: well the for loop does not work as i have said... and so does max not work... aaaaand same with counters.

Comment: @APickacks sorry about that... a little tweak will make it work :)