# Find most common object of a list and the locations of its appearances

Tags: python, list, counter

I would like to find the most common element in a list but in addition I would like to have the location of each appearance.
For example, if I have the following array:

```
array([[[1503,    0]],

       [[6600,    0]],

       [[1503,    0]],

       [[6320,    0]],

       [[1503,    0]]], dtype=int64)
```

the output I would like to have is something like: 1503, [0, 2, 4] ,
where the first output (1503) is the most common element of my list and the second output ([0, 2, 4]) is the list of locations.

I have used the following code snippet:

```
from collections import Counter

def find_majority(accounts):
    accounts_count = Counter(accounts)
    top_account = accounts_count.most_common(1)
    if len(top_account)>1 and top_account[0][1] == top_account[1][1]:
        # It is a tie
        return 0
    return top_account[0][0]
```

It gives me the most common element but I can't figure out how to upgrade this code snippet in order to find the locations as well.

Comment: You know how to find the most common value, but not how to even *try* to find that value in the list?

Comment: @ScottHunter my understanding is that he "used the following code snippet" and didn't "write the follow code snippet."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) like this:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

accounts = np.array([1503, 6600, 1503, 6320, 1503])

def find_majority(accounts):
    accounts_count = Counter(accounts)
    top_account = accounts_count.most_common(1)
    if len(top_account)>1 and top_account[0][1] == top_account[1][1]:
        # It is a tie
        return None, None
    return top_account[0][0], np.where(accounts == top_account[0][0])[0]
    
print(find_majority(accounts))
```

Output:

> (1503, array([0, 2, 4]))

Read more in [Find the most common element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520716/2411320).

Comment: '@gsamaras Thank you very much. It works and is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the value you're looking for, you can use `np.where` which takes a condition as an input. If say your most common element is 1503, `np.where(array == 1503)` returns an array of the same shape with True where you have the location.