# how can i find the most common string in a list of strings (python)

Tags: loops

I have a list that each item in it is a string (singer name) - singers = ["Abba", "queen", "the black eyed peas", "Abba"]

I want to print the singer name that has the most appearances in the list
I tried to do a for loop using count but I only received the amount of time and not the string itself..
I don't want to import tools or functions, only simple loop and methods solution
please help (:

Comment: I guess you're looking for a solution in Python? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518522/find-the-most-common-element-in-a-list.

Comment: thanks fixeria!!! i read the link you sent and it helped me find the solution i needed