# Decrease time of a function (Python)

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to create a function in python that from a list of strings will return me a dict where the key(index) shows the most repetitive character for each index between all the strings. for example a list1 = ['one', 'two', 'twin', 'who'] should return index 0=t index 1=w index 2=o index 3=n in fact the most frequent character at the index 1 between all the string is 'w'.
I found a solution but if I have lists with thousands of strings inside it will require too much time to perform. I would like to know if you can give me some help to decrease the time of execution.

Here is what I tried to do but seems too slow to perform with lists of thousands strings inside

```
list1 = ['one', 'two', 'twin', 'who']

width = len(max(list1, key=len))

chars = {}

for i, item in enumerate(zip(*[s.ljust(width) for s in list1])):
    set1 = set(item)
    if ' ' in set1:
        set1.remove(' ')
    chars[i] = max(set1, key=item.count)
print(chars)
```

Comment: Not even the standard library? "collections.Counter" would help.

Comment: nope, I need it without any libraries, like the code I poste above, but with a more efficient time

Comment: What are using `ljust` for? You are adding spaces and then remove them again. This is most likely a waste and makes your code slow.

Comment: I used ljust to establish the max width between all strings

Comment: What do you need the maximum width for if you want to count characters?

Comment: so that I can incorporate all the character even if in some cases there is only one for an index

Comment: Where is this from? Someone else had the same task just [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74396290/12671057).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether something is quick enough is a matter of use case, but this solution uses a couple of seconds to go through the default wordlist available under OS X.

[Python's `collections.Counter` implements a counter object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for you, so you don't have keep track of the counts of multiple possible values yourself.

I've paired it with `defaultdict`, which intializes a key with a function if the key is undefined - so that if we haven't already seen the index we're updating the count for, it gets initialized to a Counter object that we then update.

```py
from collections import defaultdict, Counter


with open("/usr/share/dict/words") as f:
    words = f.read().splitlines()
    letters = defaultdict(Counter)

    for word in words:
        for idx, letter in enumerate(word):
            letters[idx].update((letter, ))

for idx, counter in letters.items():
    print(idx, counter.most_common(1))
```

Whether this is quick enough depends on your use case as mentioned; it can be done a lot quicker if necessary, but it's probably quick enough. For 235 886 words the runtime is:

```
python3 letterfreq.py  2.67s user 0.04s system 99% cpu 2.734 total
```

This assumes that every word is lowercased, if not, lowercase it before adding it to your Counter object.

If you want to implement it without using the `Counter` or `defaultdict` parts of the standard library (which are just helper functionality to avoid reimplementing the same small code repeatedly), you can do the exact thing yourself manually:

```py
with open("/usr/share/dict/words") as f:
    words = f.read().splitlines()
    letter_positions = {}

    for word in words:
        for idx, letter in enumerate(word):
            if idx not in letter_positions:
                letter_positions[idx] = {}

            if letter not in letter_positions[idx]:
                letter_positions[idx][letter] = 0

            letter_positions[idx][letter] += 1

final_dict = {}

for idx, counts in letter_positions.items():
    most_popular = sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)
    print(idx, most_popular)
    final_dict[idx] = most_popular[0][0]

print(final_dict)
```

Then pick as many entries as necessary from `most_popular` when going through the list afterwards.

Since we're no longer using the `defaultdict` and `Counter` abstractions, our running time is now about a third of the previous one:

```
python3 letterfreq2.py  1.08s user 0.03s system 98% cpu 1.124 total
```

It's usually a good idea to go through what you're trying to do and formulate a strategy - i.e. "ok, I need to keep track of how many times a letter has appeared in this location .. so for that I need some way to keep values for each index .. and then for each letter ..".

Comment: thanks for the answer but I need a solution without importing any libraries

Comment: Those are part of the standard library, but sure, you can just do the same thing as those functions/objects do manually; I've added an example of that as well.

Comment: if I try it using the list1 = ['one', 'two', 'twin', 'who'] it doesn't return me a dictionary with {0:'t', 1:'w', 2:'o', 3:'n'} and that's what I need to get returned from the function when I print the dict

Comment: @terrier99uk In that case, iterate over the sorted dict and assign it to a secondary dict. This outputs a sorted list with the characters sorted in popularity - feel free to do that last part to get the exact format you need; but I've added an example of that as well.

Comment: @terrier99uk Depending on what you're asking about this for, if this is for a class assignment or similar (or any other reason, really), you need to spend to time to understand _what_ is happening and why something works the way to do.

Comment: yes I understood every step you wrote. I just wanted to improve my code. just one last question.... most_popular = sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)....here you take the most frequent chars from a defined index on a dictionary, if two characters have the same frequency how can I tell the function to get the lowest one alfabetically? for example between 'a' and 'f' with the same frequency I chose 'a'

Comment: What runtime did you get on the same data with *their* solution?

Comment: @KellyBundy Because you're sorting the dict by the value. `items()` give you a tuple with `(key, value)`, using `key=lambda x: x[1]` means that you use the value as the criteria for the sort. Their solution spent about 2.71-2.73s with the same dataset, so slightly slower than the version that uses Counter and defaultdict.

Comment: Oh, that was just me not looking up whether giving a class was considered a callable, so I just wrapped it in a lambda while writing my stream of thought. No other reason.

Comment: Could you measure one more? Their original, but with `key=''.join(item).count`. Strings count much faster than lists (and counting multiple times likely makes the single join worth it).

Comment: @KellyBundy You have all the code available here, feel free to make your own measurements and attempted changes to speed it up; I've only used `time` to time the different solution, so the time includes starting the Python interpreter as well. That way you can also attach a line profiler and do lower level optimizations as you want.

Comment: Ok, I did, tio.run happens to have such a file. That little change made it about 10x faster, and about twice as fast as your faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just make some improvements based on your algorithm.

First, you can use [itertools.zip_longest()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) instead of [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to remove the need of `ljust()` and the `width` variable:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

list1 = ['one', 'two', 'twin', 'who']

chars = {}

for i, item in enumerate(zip_longest(*list1)):
    set1 = set(item)
    if None in set1:
        set1.remove(None)
    chars[i] = max(set1, key=item.count)
print(chars)
```

Then, replace `max(set1, key=item.count)` with a [more efficent way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20872750/11806050) `Counter(item).most_common(1)[0][0]`, combined with `or set1.most_common(2)[1][0]` to filter `None` values

```py
from itertools import zip_longest
from collections import Counter

list1 = ['one', 'two', 'twin', 'who']

chars = {}

for i, item in enumerate(zip_longest(*list1)):
    set1 = Counter(item)
    chars[i] = set1.most_common(1)[0][0] or set1.most_common(2)[1][0]
print(chars)
```

As `itertools` and `collections` are Python built-in modules, you can import them directly without `pip install` them.

Comment: can you give me another solution without importing any libraries? because I need it without importing any libraries